# How can I replace pulseaudio with alsa?

Tags: 10.10, pulseaudio

I was wondering if there was an easy way of replacing pulseaudio with alsa. Pulseaudio is the biggest problem I am currently having with Ubuntu and I really want these problems to end.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question and tell us more detail what your problems are? replacing pulse audio with alsa doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If what you'd like to do is disable PulseAudio, the following steps should do it:

```
sudo sh -c "echo autospawn = no|tee -a /etc/pulse/client.conf"
touch ~/.pulse_a11y_nostart
sudo chmod 600 /usr/bin/pulse-session
killall pulseaudio
```

Note that you don't have to remove any PulseAudio-related packages to disable it.

If you'd like to temporarily disable PulseAudio, see [the answer to the relevant question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8425/how-to-temporarily-disable-pulseaudio/8427#8427).

Comment: `pulseaudio --kill` should work too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try this tutorial to fix Pulseaudio :
[HOWTO: PulseAudio Fixes & System-Wide Equalizer Suppor](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=789578)

Just do the Part A and reboot, I have done this on several differents computer that have problems with PA and it have work all the times.