# How to temporarily disable PulseAudio while running a game under Wine?

Tags: pulseaudio

Just wondering if there a way to temporarily disable PulseAudio as I am trying to run a specific Wine game (Left 4 Dead 2) and it makes the game crash occasionally.

If I kill the process it automatically comes back up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `pasuspender`. Try prefixing your wine command with it.

```
pasuspender -- wine path/to/file.exe
```

Comment: How do I reenable PulseAudio after disabling it?  I have no sound after running this, except in the program I run with pasuspender (chuck in my case), even after exiting said program (chuck).  Audio _does_ work as normal after I restart my computer.  Is my experience what is expected?

Comment: I answered my own question.  From https://wiki.debian.org/PulseAudio#Temporarily_suspend_and_run_an_application_without_PulseAudio: "While you run pasuspender, other applications won't be able to use PulseAudio. When you quit the application, the default behaviour of PulseAudio will be restored automatically."  So I have a special problem tangential to the original question.

Comment: prefixing `pasuspender` to qjackctl (`pasuspender qjackctl`) solved ages of problems for me!!! thank you so much

Answer (score 43):

In my case, I was unable to stop pulseaudio since it was being restarted automatically by systemctl.

The proper way to stop pulseaudio, in that case is:

```
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service
```

To start it again, you can use:

```
systemctl --user start pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user start pulseaudio.service
```

Comment: It could be that it's not being managed by systemctl. In that case, to stop pulseaudio, you should just `pulseaudio -k`.

Comment: My mistake, I was using service instead of systemctl.

Comment: `systemctl` accepts multiple arguments, so these can also be run as a single command, eg. `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket pulseaudio.service`

Comment: If you are using a shell with brace expansion, this can be shortened to be easier to type: `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.{socket,service}` and `systemctl --user start pulseaudio.{socket,service}`

Answer (score 33):

In `/etc/pulse/client.conf`, you can uncomment the line `autospawn=yes` and replace the yes with a "no". Of course this should be possible to set this in .pulse directory in your home directory.

A cleaner way to do this would be to create a `client.conf` in your .pulse dir in ~ and put the line "autospawn=no" in it. It would be good to turn back on autospawn after you have done what you need to do.

Comment: Or, `ed`could be used to change the config before running the game, and change it back afterwards.

Comment: second line put that you said, and first line just put: .include /etc/pulse/client.conf

Comment: Neither this or creating a `.config/pulse/client.conf` in my homedir with `autospawn=no` works for me. Pulseaudio continues to start on boot - Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: pulseaudio -k was killing the pulse audio service and not restarting by itself.  This setting is what was missing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

I use the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
echo autospawn = no >> "$HOME/.config/pulse/client.conf"
pulseaudio --kill
sed -i '/\<autospawn\>/d' "$HOME/.config/pulse/client.conf"
```

Then play the game, then re-enable PA:

```bsh
pulseaudio --start
```

Works on Xubuntu 13.10. Replace ".config/pulse" with ".pulse" in the script if it doesn't work (usually on old *buntues)

Comment: Very elegant approach.

Comment: Useless if you already have a client.conf and end up deleting it.

Comment: Then replace the `rm` with `sed -i '/\<autospawn\>/d' $HOME/.config/pulse/client.conf`...

Comment: Works beautifully without a system restart. Very appreciated, including @bufh's addition.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> type `pactl exit`

stops all pulseaudio processes. You can enter

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> type `pulseaudio`

to start it again. Unfortunately, some programs doesn't seem to sound anymore, after that. Still looking for a way to reactivate pulse without reboot…

Comment: `pactl exit` does not stop pulseaudio completely on my machine, it is immediately restarted (just like with `pulseaudio -k`).

Comment: `pactl exit` worked for me. With `pulseaudio -k` it restarted automatically even though I had autorespawn disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Ubuntu Tips. It works fine on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

[Ubuntu Tip: Turning PulseAudio On and Off](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/7130/2)

Answer (score -2):

What I did.... stopped it from respawning because it couldn't find it....... right click the /etc folder in the file browser (open as root) create a new folder called pulseoff, then move the pulse folder into it (drag and drop). The system doesn't have the command to look there for it. If you want to start it again, cut it from the pulseoff folder, go up a step to the /etc folder and paste it there...... Some people like to make it out to be harder than it really is with editing files and stuff and mostly those edits don't work I tried them. Do it the easy way. I restarted the machine and checked the system monitor before posting this, pulseaudio is not running and sucking up memory.