# How can I restart pulseaudio without having to logout?

Tags: pulseaudio

Sometimes the pulseaudio service stops and it doesn't restart itself when I open an audio file with banshee or totem.

How I can make pulseaudio start again without having to logout?

Comment: Could I be so bold as to suggest accepting TikTak's answer? It works for me whereas the answer with the most upvotes has extra unnecessary steps.

Comment: TikTak's answer is not the way one should restart PulseAudio in Ubuntu 2020 releases. systemctl should be used to restart PulseAudio.

Comment: Also note that the default audio system is Pipewire since Ubuntu 22.10 so you may need this instead: https://askubuntu.com/questions/230888/is-there-another-way-to-restart-the-sound-system-if-pulseaudio-alsa-dont-work/1374982#1374982

Answer (score 247):

I solved my problem.

1. Check if any pulseaudio instance is running:

   ```
    pulseaudio --check
   ```

It normally prints no output, just exit code. `0` means running.
Mine were not running, so I just advanced to step 3.

2. If any instance is running, kill it:

   ```
    pulseaudio -k
   ```
3. Finally, start pulseaudio again as a daemon:

   ```
    pulseaudio -D
   ```
4. Start banshee again and enjoy!

Comment: For me --check didn't show anything, even though -k stopped audio playback, implying pulseaudio was running.

Comment: For me, pulseaudio gets so hung up (forgetting a sink) that `pulseaudio -k` doesn't do the job. After `sudo killall pulseaudio`, everything starts up again and works fine. (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: fyi, the step 1: "`pulseaudio --check` _normally prints no output_, just exit code 0 which means running" => so, there is no output, it's running; but, if you want to check the exit code anyway, run: `echo $?` which should print `0` if it's running.  (the `$?` is the exit code of the previous command. If you run it twice, then it prints the exit code of `echo`)

Comment: You could combine steps 1 and 2 like so: `pulseaudio --check && pulseaudio -k` - it will only run the kill if check exits with 0 (running)

Comment: Combining Raphael and Jeff's observations, I frequently find myself running `pulseaudio --check && (pulseaudio -k || sudo killall pulseaudio)`

Comment: @NickBull Shoudn't it be `pulseaudio --check && pulseaudio -k || sudo killall pulseaudio` ?

Answer (score 112):

Pulseaudio is a user service, so:

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

Also there is this:

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.socket
```

For checks replace `restart` with `status`.

Comment: To be run as normal user, the user which runs pulseaudio of course. Should be the top answer. And I have to say that for me pulseaudio was functioning well. But after some libraries where upgraded it had to be restarted.

Comment: This is the right answer for me. `pulseaudio -k ` does or returns nothing at all. The other option that worked was `killall pulseaudio`.

Comment: This is the correct answer for Ubuntu & other distros using SystemD to launch PulseAudio as a logged in user.

Answer (score 63):

In a standard setup running `pulseaudio -k` restarts the daemon. Nothing else to do.

In case pulseaudio is not running typing `pulseaudio` without further options will start the daemon using defaults in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

User-defined settings in `~/.pulse/` or `~/.config/pulse/` will override system-wide settings. In case of issues it will often help to delete these directories before restarting pulseaudio.

For details see [PulseAudio Wiki](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/PerfectSetup/).

Comment: `/usr/bin/pulseaudio` returns `bash: /usr/bin/pulseaudio: Permission denied` even though the file permissions seem fine: `-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 root root 87K Jun 21 08:09 /usr/bin/pulseaudio`why

Comment: because the daemon is running as root

Comment: `rm ~/.config/pulse/*` followed by `pulseaudio -k` did the trick.

Comment: @Takkat What ?? `pulseaudio -k` kills the daemon, period. The manpage is very clear on that. You have to run `pulseaudio --start` afterwards to start the daemon.

Comment: @Atralb did you try my answer? As stated, in it's default installation [pulseaudio will respawn automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8425/how-to-temporarily-disable-pulseaudio). If you then try to start the server a second time it will give you an error. If respawning was broken you may have a serious issue with your audio setup.

Comment: `pulseaudio -k` did the trick!  I didn't even have to restart any of my players as their sound was working great right after running that command.  +1  :)

Comment: pulseaudio wasnt running (I use the EQ). After killing it, it never came back. just typing `pulseaudio` saved the day. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Following works for me on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Comment: This just kills the sound completely.

Comment: @mathtick for me, 'pulseaudio -D' worked afterwards to restore the missing audio. This starts pulseaudio again.

Answer (score 16):

Use the service command (Ubuntu 14.04 or older only):

```
sudo service pulseaudio restart
```

Comment: I unfortunately don't have any specific knowledge in addition to the very explicit command. If if had, I would have had explained more. If you have any idea, please be my guest.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04: `Failed to restart pulseaudio.service: Unit pulseaudio.service not found.`

Comment: pulseaudio runs in user mode (i.e. the currently logged-in user), no "service" registered. So that command cannot work.

Comment: Indeed, pulseaudio runs in user mode. See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1123869/67745)

Answer (score 11):

Run the following commands:

```
pulseaudio --check
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's how to do it in Ubuntu 15.10:

1. Launch Terminal
2. Run `pulseaudio -k` to kill the running daemon. You will get an error only if no daemon was running, otherwise no messages will appear.
3. Ubuntu will attempt to restart the daemon automatically assuming there are no problems with the configuration. You can run `pulseaudio --check` to check that Pulseaudio is running. A clean exit (no message) from the `check` command indicates that the daemon has started successfully. Otherwise, run `pulseaudio --start` to launch the daemon. If you recently changed your configuration file and the daemon fails to start, check your file for errors and check the syslog (with the SystemLog app) for any messages from Pulseaudio.

Answer (score 8):

If the pulseaudio failing to work is related to S3 sleep (Suspend to RAM), the real cause may be audio hardware problem and then you have to do heavy-handed full reset:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload && sleep 2 && pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Yeah, it needs to be done twice with small delay. I don't know why but this seems to work every time.

If you have multiple desktop environments in parallel (fast user switching)

```
sudo killall pulseaudio && sudo alsa force-reload && sleep 2 && sudo killall pulseaudio && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Answer (score 5):

You would run this command to restart PulseAudio in Ubuntu 2020 releases:

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

Comment: finally, a command that works on ubuntu 20. Also not sure what caused the service to not restart itself after reboot, but it happened after a recent update.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add my penny's worth to my namesake @rolf's `systemD`answer.
The scenario:
Pulseaudio is locked up tight

You've tried:

```sh
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
```

```sh
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

```sh
systemctl --user reset-failed pulseaudio.service
```

Still stubbonly it shows:

```
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2022-08-07 17:43:39 CEST; 8min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
    Process: 6598 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 6598 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 07 17:43:39 pc1 systemd[1063]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 07 17:43:39 pc1 systemd[1063]: Failed to start Sound Service.
Aug 07 17:43:39 pc1 systemd[1063]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 07 17:43:39 pc1 systemd[1063]: Stopped Sound Service.
Aug 07 17:43:39 pc1 systemd[1063]: pulseaudio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 07 17:43:39 pc1 systemd[1063]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 07 17:43:39 pc1 systemd[1063]: Failed to start Sound Service.
```

The key here is that the restart counter has been exceeded.
If you manually run:
`pulseaudio -vvvv`

You may find the final lines say:

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

Here, you need to find your user id's /run/user/1000/pulse directory, where the number 1000 is my user id number

Get your uid from the command: `id`

In the the pulse run directory is a file called `pid`
, delete it!

Try starting `pulseaudio -vvvv` again, only to discover that it's bound to the Dbus or the bind Address already in use

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: D-Bus name org.PulseAudio1 already taken.
or
E: [pulseaudio] socket-server.c: bind(): Address already in use
```

So: `ps -ef | grep pulseaudio` to find any process still running it and kill it with

`kill -15` pid number from grep

Now you can restart pulseaudio:

```
systemctl --user start pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
```

or:

**You could logout and log back in again** :)