# Laggy sound, how can I know what the problem is?

Tags: 11.10, sound

Lately, I've been experiencing laggy sound. The only usable syndrome I've found can be the fact, that is the Sound settings in the Output tab the Connector keeps changing to Analog Headphones from Analog Output, this takes only a few milliseconds before it jumps back to Analog Output.

This has been really annoying, because I can't play games, listen to music, and enjoy Ubuntu in all of it's beauty. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For specifications see: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dh67cl.html It seems to be a Realtek ALC892.

Comment: Changelog http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/linux_3.0.0-13.22/changelog - http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-meta_3.0.0.13.15/changelog

Comment: what was the point of the comment?

Comment: Do you have a laptop? If you do then your problem might be this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64184/sound-noise-problem-on-laptops

Comment: nope.. Not a laptop :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this is a pulseaudio issue - one solution is to use ALSA instead of pulseaudio.

This will loose the sound indicator together with the pulseaudio tools.  To change your sound use `alsamixergui` or `gnome-alsamixer`

```
sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install alsa-base alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils linux-sound-base alsamixergui gnome-alsamixer
```

Then reboot.

To reinstate pulseaudio:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop indicator-sound
```

---

As we have discussed, it is worth checking if this is a specific problem in 11.10 that could have been resolved in the upcoming 12.04 release.  To do this, download either the [Alpha 1 release](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/alpha-1/) of 12.04 or the [daily-build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/).

Use Unetbootin to write the ISO to a USB stick and boot from that into the 12.04 live USB.

On confirmation that this is a specific 11.10 issue, then the problem is likely to be a kernel specific issue.

You have four choices:

1. Stick with what you have and wait until 12.04 is officially released in April
2. Upgrade to the 12.04 Alpha - only do this is you are prepared for breakages.  Only do this if you are happy and experienced enough to overcome alpha quality issues such as non booting, graphical issues etc.
3. Install 12.04 as a dual boot with 11.10 or as a virtualbox guest install in 11.10
4. Upgrade the 11.10 kernel to the 12.04 kernel.

If you want to try the 12.04 kernel then first the important proviso:

**drive-image backup you current 11.10 install**

I'm not kidding - upgrading the kernel is not to be trivialised and can leave you in a non-booting scenario.  Use a good quality drive-image software such as clonezilla.

Step 1 - temporarily change your sources to precise:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/oneiric/precise/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Step 2 - download and install the precise kernel

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-headers-generic
```

Step 3 - change your sources back to oneiric:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/precise/oneiric/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Then reboot.

Once logged in test that you have successfully booted into the kernel 3.2 by running:

```
uname -a
```

Comment: not working, all the same..

Comment: Is there a way I can manually update my kernel to 3.2 with Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: Do you mean just booting from the live CD/USB and playing audio will be able to determine if the sound works as it should or not?

Comment: Banshee basically. Sometimes the Flash Player plugin for YouTube. And where can I get the Ubuntu 12.04 iso file?

Comment: I cannot find the Ubuntu 12.04 entry in UNetbootin menu. Do I have to download and select the daily build iso?

Comment: Okay, I'll just select the ISO. Thanks. Will tell if everything works a little later.

Comment: Well it fixed the issue. Te sound works properly. That's why it worked fine on Fedora. Should I wait for 12.04 or install the 3.2 kernel on my 11.10?

Comment: ok - I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from your description if this is your problem or not, but try this workaround for glitchy (crackling, skipping) audio:

Using any editor, open `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
# command line
sudo -e /etc/pulse/default.pa

# graphical
gksu gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Find the line `load-module module-udev-detect` and add "tsched=0" to the end of the line

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

Log out and back in

[Original post on the forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9948061&postcount=2)

[Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/621430?comments=all)

Comment: Did not work, same...

Comment: OK, try this driver http://files.spacefish.biz/LinuxPkg-5.15rc1.tar.bz2 Unpack it and run the install script as root. Then I would try rebooting

Comment: Installing the driver removed all my hardware from the Sound settings. But before installing the driver, I've noticed some detail, and it is pretty weird. When I go to Sound settings, in the "Output" tab the "Output volume" keeps going down for 5% or so in a few milliseconds and then jumps back to 100%, during this process (if the "Internal Audio Analog Stereo" is selected as the default device), the connector, just under the hardware selection jumps from "Analog output" to "Analog headphones" for the same few milliseconds. I do think that it is pretty weird, it can help though I think.

Comment: just to ask the obvious, did you reboot or at least restart pulse audio ?