# Play sound through two or more outputs/devices

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack

I have one sound card and one pair of Bluetooth headphones. I want to play my audio through both my sound card and my Bluetooth headphones.

I believe Windows has checkboxes that allow you to "check" outputs to enable/disable them, but Ubuntu seemingly has the equivalent of radio selectors (you can only select one at a time).

Bonus question:
On a similar note, I have 5 analog output channels on my sound card (in addition to my digital & HDMI audio) -- I would like to be able to determine what comes out of each of those ports (e.g. "front speakers" on all 5 or "front", "center", "back", etc).

Comment: I have read all answers, checking answer date too. What is the current solution for ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Yes, the version of `paprefs` in Ubuntu 18.04 repos is useless (because it still thinks GConf is in fashion and hence fails to work). The best alternative is to, you know, load the `module-combine-sink` of PulseAudio yourself (because that's all `paprefs` does behind-the-scene anyway). Use command `pactl load-module module-combine-sink` and check the Sounds section of Ubuntu Settings.

Comment: In Ubuntu 19.10 solution with paprefs works out of box again.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 - `paprefs` worked for all hard-connected speakers, after closing all audio settings & restarting the pulsaudio `killall pulseaudio` however it disconnected my bluetooth speaker - had to reconnect and switch to it and back to the multioutput :)

Comment: it works but the timing is a mess. i understand now why no professional wanted to write software for linux. the complete audio architecture is a bit of a mess. pulseaudio being more network oriented and jack single audio device. it is hard to create tight sync between multiple audio devices. The synchronisation issues are simply not easy to solve.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

With [`paprefs`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/paprefs.1.html) you have access to a virtual output device that enables simultaneous output to all attached sound cards and devices:

```
sudo apt install paprefs
```

Then in the terminal run `paprefs`, select *Simultaneous Output* tab, and check *Add virtual output for simultaneous output on all local sounds cards*.

[image: paprefs]

The additionally created audio output device for simultaneous output may be selected in the *Output* tab from the PulseAudio *Sound Preferences* menu (`pavucontrol`):

[image: pavucontrol screenshot]

In this example it is shown for an HDMI-device, but, as soon as your Bluetooth device is recognized, it will also be available for simultaneous output.

The changes may need a restart of PulseAudio to take effect, either by logging out and back in to your session or by running `pulseaudio -k` in a terminal.

---

In case `paprefs` does not do the job or if you prefer to have `paprefs` not installed, use this command from the command line:

```
pactl load-module module-combine-sink
```

To unload the module from the command line and reset PulseAudio to defaults, just restart PulseAudio with:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

or issue:

```
pactl unload-module module-combine-sink
```

Comment: This gets the job done.  As I get deeper into audio development, I would really like to be able to select specific devices and/or ports, though.

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer: you may be interested in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line/14083#14083). For changing ports see also the pulseaudio wiki I linked to there.

Comment: but what if i want to use the built-in speakers along with an audio line that does not have bluetooth? i used this solution but since the audio jack is not connected to something that has an audio card, sound options does not recognize it...

Comment: Is there any way to fix the delay between bluetooth speaker and build in speakers? It seems to me that they are quite in syc one time and far appart another.

Comment: The delay comes from buffers needed for the A2DP protocol. Not much we can do about this, unfortunately.

Comment: this one doesn't work for me in 18.04. If you know how I can do this with ALSA please help me here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1042485/586277

Comment: doesnt work for me in ubuntu 16.04. I don't see any such option like "Simultaneous output" in the sound preferances window

Comment: @node_man: did you install and set up **paprefs** as shown in the first part of my answer? It would be a prerequisite for creating a simultaneous sink.

Comment: yes I followed the steps correctly but it didn't worked. Then I tried it on another ubuntu machine and it worked. So I reinstalled pulse audio on my machine and now it's working. The problem was pulseaudio -k was not killing pulseaudio it was throwing some permission errors. now it's fixed. thank you

Comment: How can one control each output device's volume independently? If that can't be done, this answer is almost useless.

Comment: @Jollywatt - Separate volume control of each audio device is possible through ***PulseAudio Preferences*** (`pavucontrol`), under both 'Playback' and 'Output' tabs.

Comment: Didn't create a device on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @Velkan: thanks for the notice. Paprefs appears to be broken. Try with the command I gave in an edit to this answer.

Comment: @Takkat, yea, I did instead add the `load-module module-combine-sink` into `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` as other comments say. It's working.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.10, too.

Comment: @Velkan you need to CLOSE ALL AUDIO SETTINGS WINDOWS, then `killall pulseaudio` and then reopen them when audio starts again, tested on Ubuntu 20.04 right now and it works

Comment: @Takkat however I had a different issue - killing pulsaudio also disconnected my bluetooth speaker - I had to reconnect to it again and switch output device to the bluetooth speaker and back to the virtual multioutput :)

Answer (score 29):

### Ubuntu

I've just confirmed this solution still works on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

1. **Install**: Open terminal and type `sudo apt install paprefs` go to the tab exactly as per the picture above and select the option.
2. **Initial Run**:

   1. Remaining in terminal, type `pulseaudio -k` to kill and restart pulseaudio ([this way](https://askubuntu.com/a/1123869/349837) with current systemd pulseaudio user service).
   2. Then go to your sound settings and you will see the option to output to multiple sound devices.
   3. Props to whoever wrote paprefs it's a brilliant little piece of software I would actually like to see included in Ubuntu without requiring additional installation.

### Apple Mac OS X

A similar solution is available via an included piece of software and whats so great about `pulseaudio` is that the sound seems to be perfectly in-sync from both outputs so it must be adjusting for the lag as well which is why its so impressive; otherwise we would be hearing a slightly delayed version from one output and another.

Comment: thanks for doing the work to check if solution is still valid!

Comment: This also works on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: Thanks, just confirmed this works in Linux Mint 20. It's per user so you have to do the command as the desktop user.

Answer (score 14):

In Kubuntu 18.04, Plasma 5.12 `paprefs` is not needed, as a similar setting is already there:

[image]

A new output option should become available after reboot, called “Simultaneous output”.

[image]

Or in `pavucontrol`:

[image]

---

In 18.10 with Plasma 5.13.5 that “Simultaneous output” option has been removed, so `paprefs` is needed.

Comment: "Simultaneous output" is still available on my ArchLinux with KDE 5.19.2

Answer (score 10):

I could not get Takkat's proposal work out of the box in Debian 8.7, although I restarted the system. 
I assume you have completed Takkat's proposal in installing `paprefs`. 
Extension on Takkat's answer which works based on Arch Linux [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Simultaneous_HDMI_and_analog_output) where keep analog input and Pulse calls that "duplex"

```
# /etc/pulse/default.pa
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180374/16920
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hdmi:0
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined
set-default-sink combined
```

Then restart pulseaudio:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Comment: For me, this one worked when I had device="hw:0,0" as per `aplay -l` (see https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=264540#p1436479)

Comment: Make sure to put at top of file! This works for me (hw:0,0) on Ubuntu 18.04.2, playing on two HDMI monitors, after I moved the lines to the top.

Answer (score 10):

Because `LeonidMew` was asking about 18.04 (I'm using `18.04.2`), here's my version.

The GUI `paprefs` tried to combine one HDMI with one analog output, instead of both hdmi. So I edited the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` as described by `Léo Léopold Hertz`

```
$ gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa  # make changes as in method a or b below
$ pulseaudio -k # then restart pulseaudio
```

Both the following methods work on their own, so pick one (**make sure to add these lines to the top of the file**, I put it right after `.fail` ! Otherwise it doesn't work).

### Method A

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined
```

### Method B

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,3 sink_name=hdmi
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,7 sink_name=hdmi2
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined slaves=hdmi,hdmi2
set-default-sink hdmi-combined
```

---

### Reference

#### Method A

For reference, the `hw:0,0` comes from `aplay -l`

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

#### Method B

And the `1:7` and `1:3` comes from

```
$ pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'alsa.device ' -e 'alsa.subdevice '
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo>
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.device = "1"
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1>
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.device = "7"
```

On the GNOME "sound settings" I set the other HDMI from 2nd monitor as output, and then re-ran the command

```
$ pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'alsa.device ' -e 'alsa.subdevice '
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo>
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.device = "1"
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.device = "3"
```

To verify these numbers are correct, I ran

```
$ aplay -D plughw:1,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav
$ aplay -D plughw:1,7 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav
```

which sounded on their respective monitors.

Answer (score 8):

To complement the excellent answer from Takkat, I found the default name given to the new device was excessively long and distorted the Sound Settings dialog. In order to shorten that name, I had to additionally execute the following command:

```
gconftool --set --type string /system/pulseaudio/modules/combine/args0 sink_properties=device.description=Combined
```

[image: Sound settings with combined device]

Comment: How do I undo this?!

Answer (score 0):

### Nowadays

Actually, with pipewire, just the GUI part seems to bee missing for this to work (in GNOME, as of GNOME 45).

Actually, there are many GUI tools for this and similar tasks (like distorting audio or so), just search for [pipewire on Flathub e.g.](https://flathub.org/de/apps/search?q=pipewire).

I tested some and found [**Helvum** to be good and working for that use case.](https://flathub.org/de/apps/org.pipewire.Helvum). In the self-proclaimed “graphical patchbay for PipeWire”. You can just connect the same source twice there or mix that up even more:
[image].

I.e. drag and drop the source from the left to the right, where the audio devices are. (Note `FL` is left audio and `FR` is right audio)
The disadvantage/important thing to note is the source only appears once it has audio output and you need to configure this *for each application*. (though, the benefit of course is, you can configure it separately)

The benefit is this also works on immutable distros.

### My tries

Before using Fedora Silverblue 39 I tried using [the `paprefs`](https://askubuntu.com/q/78174/606016):

```sh
$ rpm-ostree install paprefs             
Checking out tree 9450953... done
Enabled rpm-md repositories: fedora rpmfusion-free fedora-cisco-openh264 updates rpmfusion-free-updates updates-archive
Importing rpm-md... done
rpm-md repo 'fedora' (cached); generated: 2023-11-01T00:12:39Z solvables: 70825
rpm-md repo 'rpmfusion-free' (cached); generated: 2023-11-04T16:49:08Z solvables: 445
rpm-md repo 'fedora-cisco-openh264' (cached); generated: 2023-12-12T17:22:46Z solvables: 4
rpm-md repo 'updates' (cached); generated: 2024-03-18T02:04:08Z solvables: 24253
rpm-md repo 'rpmfusion-free-updates' (cached); generated: 2024-03-10T16:19:26Z solvables: 164
rpm-md repo 'updates-archive' (cached); generated: 2024-03-18T02:34:06Z solvables: 36849
Resolving dependencies... done
error: Could not depsolve transaction; 1 problem detected:
 Problem: package pulseaudio-module-gsettings-16.1-5.fc39.x86_64 from fedora requires libpulsecore-16.1.so()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pulseaudio-module-gsettings-16.1-5.fc39.x86_64 from fedora requires pulseaudio(x86-64) = 16.1-5.fc39, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pipewire-pulseaudio-1.0.4-2.fc39.x86_64 from @System conflicts with pulseaudio provided by pulseaudio-16.1-5.fc39.x86_64 from fedora
  - package pipewire-pulseaudio-1.0.4-2.fc39.x86_64 from @System conflicts with pulseaudio-daemon provided by pulseaudio-16.1-5.fc39.x86_64 from fedora
  - package pulseaudio-16.1-5.fc39.x86_64 from fedora conflicts with pulseaudio-daemon provided by pipewire-pulseaudio-1.0.4-2.fc39.x86_64 from @System
  - package paprefs-1.2-5.fc39.x86_64 from fedora requires pulseaudio-module-gsettings, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
```