# Is it possible to connect two wireless headsets (Bluetooth or RF)?

Tags: sound, hardware, bluetooth

I wonder if it is possible to have two wireless headsets connected simultaneously? Is this possible with USB headsets or with Bluetooth?

The purpose is for a group chat so that the microphone input is mixed and then shared 
over the internet, and the incoming audio stream is sent to both headsets.

Comment: Do you need to connect audio output only, or is it microphone inputs too?

Comment: Only ouput, although input for video conference would be nice too.

Comment: For audio **output** only we can add a virtual device for simultaneous output on all attached devices (see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/78179/3940) for details). We may need all devices to be recognized before we add the simultanoeus output device.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, are you still looking for an answer? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Are you still interested in an answer to this question? Some other people are having similar questions. If you are still around and willing to take ownership of this one then we can open it, otherwise I can just have them ask a new question. Thanks!

Comment: No, I don't use Ubuntu as my primary desktop anymore.