# How to play normal and bluetooth speakers simultaneously?

Tags: bluetooth, speakers

I have one normal and one bluetooth speaker. When I activate the bluetooth speaker, the normal speaker stops to play. There is a way to play normal and bluetooth speakers simultaneously in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some people have had success with simultaneous audio output using [PulseAudioPreferences](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/paprefs/).

It essentially creates a virtual audio output device encompassing more than one actual audio output device.

According to this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices), this paprefs solution was still working under 14.04 LTS.