# Play audio throught multiple audio devices (without using UI)

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I have 2 soundcards, and I want the sound that is played to play on both. I know how to do this via the GUI ([Play sound through two or more outputs/devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices)), but my case is different:

- I don't use pulseaudio, it's alsa directly
- I want to use the commandline

Any ideas?
Thx!

Comment: In case both cards are recognized you should be able to simply unmute both using `alsamixer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a new device in your `~/.asoundrc` or in `/etc/asound.conf`:

```perl
pcm.both {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type multi
        slaves.a {
            pcm "hw:0"   # or whatever
            channels 2
        }
        slaves.b {
            pcm "hw:1"   # ...
            channels 2
        }
        bindings [
            { slave a channel 0 }
            { slave a channel 1 }
            { slave b channel 0 }
            { slave b channel 1 }
        ]
    }
    ttable [
        [ 1 0 1 0 ]
        [ 0 1 0 1 ]
    ]
}
```

Then use the `both` device name: `aplay -D both something.wav`.

If the clock speeds of these devices do not exactly match, the `multi` plugin will eventually over-/underrun one of the device's buffers
(PulseAudio would be able to resample on the fly).

Comment: that works! do you have any idea how to set this device as default?

Comment: Name it `default` instead.

Comment: appreciated! (for the record, it appears to be `pcm.!default`)