# mix signals from two sound cards to one virtual sound device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

i read this interesting thread on splitting the same audio to more simultaneus sound card usig a virtual sound card (speakers):
[Play sound through two or more outputs/devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices)

but what i have to do if i need to mix more signals incoming from microphones (attached to different sound cards) to one virtual sound card (capture)?

Comment: see [ALSA and PulseAudio - recording multiple input devices?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/alsa-and-pulseaudio-recording-multiple-input-devices-877614/)