# Make speakers and headphones work together at the same time

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

It may be a bit strange, but I need speakers work when headphones plugged.

I search the web and find only the issues when both of them work together. My system works fine. When I plug in my headphones speakers are off. But I need to enable them. Is it possible? It would be also cool to know how to roll things back to normal state.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

**--update--**

Sorry, I forgot to say that I already inspected `alsamixer` and I see this. I tried to disable `Auto-Mute Mode`, but with no effect. I also changed the speaker volume, but have same result.
[image]

Comment: Check `alsamixer` (type it in command line) settings. You probably just need to unmute in-line.

Comment: do you want both playing all sound Or some on speakers and some on headphones/

Comment: **2Rinzwind** Please, see the question for the answer. **2ravery** I  want both play same sound. Just playing simultaneously.

Comment: pulse turns off speakers when headphones are plugged in. You might be able to do what you want with a loopback device to double the output and send one to speaker and one to headphones. Unfortunately I can't give specifics on how to do it. If the switching is done by the sound card itself, you may not be able to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play sound through two or more outputs/devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your time everybody, playing farther I eventually noticed `MM` sign below the volume bar. It means `muted`. It's changed via `m` button. Speaker volume and auto mute must be also properly setup.