# Boosting low volume on 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

I have a Thinkpad T530 and the max volume on Linux (Xubuntu 16.04) is quite low compared to Windows on the same macine.

You can push the volume above 100% with the volume control UI, but it resets to 100% whenever I change volume with the keyboard keys, so I'm looking for a better solution. I'd also rather not use external speakers (its a laptop), so I'm trying to do this with software.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. `pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo 150%` - also resets volume when I touch the keyboard controls. No dice.
2. Checked mixer levels in `alsamixer`. Everything relevant (Master/Speakers/PCM) is already at 100%.
3. Created an ALSA softvol control in `/etc/asound.conf`, as described [here](https://alien.slackbook.org/blog/adding-an-alsa-software-pre-amp-to-fix-low-sound-levels/) and [here](https://alsa.opensrc.org/How_to_use_softvol_to_control_the_master_volume). I got the control to appear in alsamixer, but it has no effect on volume. **However**, it does work if I kill the pulseaudio daemon and just use ALSA.

Right now I'm attempting to modify my `asound.conf` to work with PulseAudio, but think that I may be out of my depth here.

It doesn't seem like I can use a [`pulse` type](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Expose_PulseAudio_sources.2C_sinks_and_mixers_to_ALSA) PCM device as a slave in ALSA to get the softvol amp to work, and I have no idea how to route the default audio device to it when PulseAudio is running anyways.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: According to your description you did not try `pavucontrol` to see the volume setting of  sources and sinks?

Comment: I tried `pavucontrol`. My sources/sinks are at 100%. It does produce audio, its just quieter than I know the machine is capable of.

Comment: What are your keyboard keys working on? Usually, they only work on the default sink, so you could increase the _source_ volume without being affected by the volume keys.

Comment: There is another possibility: Activate [simultaneous output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices) in pulseaudio, even if you only have one output device, and set the new sink as default device. The volume keys now only affect the virtual device; you may increase the volume on the physical device which then should be kept..

Comment: Keys are tied to one of my sinks. I tried `pacmd set-source-volume 0 100%` to set the source volume, but it had no effect. The simultaneous input trick did work though :) I just had to add `pacmd set-default-sink combined` to my `~/.bash_profile` so that applications used the virtual sink.

I'm still very curious about getting it done with ALSA, but this works for now. Thanks ridgy!

Comment: Well, your source volume already was at 100%, according to your post. So you would have to increase it to more than that (might try with pavucontrol, but only for the source active). I don't know a way to increase volumes with ALSA to more than 100%; think it is not possible.

Comment: Right, I forgot to include that I tried `pacmd set-source-volume 0 150%` and `pacmd set-source-volume 0 10%` as well, no effect with either. Changing the source index (though I'm sure it was 0 based on `pacmd source-list`) also didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The terms `source`, `sink`, and `client` have to be distinguished clearly. You can best see that in `pavucontrol`:

- In the rightmost tab (Configuration), you set the profiles for the hardware (source, sink, both, #channels etc.)
- in the fourth tab (Input Devices), you define the sources and their volumes, which are hardware sources as well as virtual sources and monitors of sinks
- in the third tab (Output devices), you define the sinks and their volumes and maybe some other options, which are hardware sinks as well as virtual ones.

The volumes and other properties shown here may be set using `pacmd` or `pactl`. Setting *source* volume means setting the volume of (hardware or virtual) input devices (like microphone or monitors), *not* the volume of the running applications.

These are called "clients" in the terminology of PA and set in the first tab (Playback), where you are able to set the desired sink and volume for each running application separately. This is application and user specific and thus stored in a database in `~/.config/pulse/<something>-stream-volumes.tdb`. You might look at that information with `tdbdump`, but there is not much to see.

So `pavucontrol`(which is just another client) remembers this information for the next start of the client. But you cannot modify that with `pacmd` or `pactl`, which are clients for the configuration of the server itself. From the command line you may only use `paplay` to set sink and volume of itself.

As the module for the simultaneous output is sortof a client as well (a virtual stream), which connects an application stream to more than one sink, you may handle that like other streams, and it will be saved in the above mentioned tdb. You might use any module that works similar, but this one is preconfigered and the simplest one I know. You may test the behaviour when logging in as different user; you will have to set the volume again.