# GMusicbrowser and Simultaneous ALSA Output for two audio device

Tags: sound, alsa, gstreamer

I have one USB and one Onboard sound device. Using GMusicplayer for playing music through the USB with ALSA output:

[image: GMusicbrowser ALSA]

Since I can not add (or I don't know how to add) the other device on GMusicbrowser ALSA device settings I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/78179/586277) but it is about pulseaudio and I don't want to use pulseaudio for my USB device.

I want to use ALSA for GMusicbrowser pass to the USB device and  whatever that is playing by GMusicbrowser pass to the onboard device (with pulseaudio or ALSA).

aplay -l result:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: WooAudio [WooAudio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I want: whatever 2,0 plays, 0,0 play that too.