# separating audio output in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound

Can I separate audio output in two device? Devices that I want to output are laptop speaker and headphone.

There was no results in googling. And in setting, there was no button for generate for separating.

My laptop is MSI62 2QF. I frequently change hearing position so I want to change setting.

Comment: I don't know your hardware, but I'd try using `pavucontrol` (Pulse Audio volume control) to see if you can select output.   I've had great success on some machines with this, less on others & assumed it was hardware that controlled what functions I could/couldn't do (*I didn't care enough to explore further*)

Comment: `separate audio output in two device` it is unclear: do you want *two* playback sources each in a separate output or do you want *one* playback in both internal speakers and headset?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play sound through two or more outputs/devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices)

Answer (score 3):

`separate audio output in two device` it is unclear: do you want *two* playback sources each in a separate output or do you want *one* playback in both internal speakers and headset?

---

If you want **two or more playback sources each in a separate output**: that is possible with `pavucontrol` (PulseAudio Volume Control): you should be able to output each different playback source to a separate device, like for example VLC to headset and Qmmp to internal speakers.

[image]

Depending on your desktop the same options may be present in the default audio volume settings (e.g. in Plasma:*Audio Volume Settings > Audio Volume > (tab)Applications*).

[image]

---

If you want **playback in all output devices at the same time** (e.g. in both internal speakers and headset): as indicated [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/play-sound-through-multiple-devices-linux/) install `paprefs` and set it (selecting the “Simultaneous output”).

[image]

But I am in Kubuntu 18.04, and in Plasma 5.12 `paprefs` is not needed, as a similar setting is already there:

[image]

A new output option should become available after reboot, called “Simultaneous output”.

[image]

Comment: In 18.10 with Plasma 5.13.5 that “Simultaneous output” option has been removed, so `aprefs` is needed.