# Remove Audio output device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, default, mute

I've only just started using Ubuntu w/ dual monitors.

[I tried running a command to play audio through both monitors but it didn't work.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices) Now I'm stuck with the sound muting every time I pause/restart etc. as it switched to "digital output (S/PDIF) - Family 17h (Models 00h- 0fh) HD Audio Controller"

How do I remove this from my output devices?

Thanks in advance!