# How to play audio from Laptop Speaker and Bluetooth Speaker simultaneously on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, speakers, bluetooth-speaker

I am using ubuntu 20.04, I have a google nest mini which I am using as a Bluetooth speaker. I am trying to play audio from both my laptop speaker and the google nest at the same time. I found some solutions online, which seemed to work for older versions of Ubuntu, but nothing for the version I am using. I tried them and one of them([The first answer form this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices)) works, which apparently creates a virtual device that broadcasts the audio to both speakers. The command was

`pactl load-module module-combine-sink`.

This does play audio from both speakers, but there is a significantly noticeable delay in the audio output of the Bluetooth speaker compared to that of the laptop speaker, which defeats the whole purpose.

Can anyone point me towards a solution to this issue?

Thanks in advance