# How to connect multiple Bluetooth headsets at the same time?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

My girlfriend and I like to watch movies outside, but it's very noisy so we prefer to use headsets. We would like to watch movies using two different Bluetooth headsets. Both work individually on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, but I'm pretty sure there's a way to hack Pulseaudio or something in order to have the same output on these two devices at the same time.

I found [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/78179) and it somehow work, but it seems that it only applies for multiple hardware devices (sound cards). That's not what I want to achieve here.

Any idea if this is even possible without having the recompile the kernel?

Thanks

Comment: My personal experience for what it is worth is that both the Bluetooth dongle and the headsets must support multi connection at the same time.

Comment: AFAIK both need to be version 5.