# 3.5 mm audio and Bluetooth working at the same time

Tags: bluetooth

My media PC runs Ubuntu, as does my laptop. When my wife and I watch a movie either she hears it or I do. On Bluetooth my aids allow me to hear the spoken word in a movie, trust me as a hard of hearing person this is great. Downside is she can't hear it.
So my question is, is there a way via hardware or software that both normal 3.5 mm audio and Bluetooth can work at the same time and be in sync?

thanks for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play sound through two or more outputs/devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices) A very old question but has recent answers for current Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Sound settings is supposed to have an option for "simultaneous output" to all sound devices. Is it not there? Not working? Please edit your question.