# Play audio through 2+ bluetooth devices

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth

I do not have surround sound speaker setup and was hoping that I can imitate some level of that through 2 (or more) sets of wireless earbuds when watching a movie with someone on my laptop.

Basically a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices), except it's for Ubuntu 22.04.2. The answer as given in there does not seem to work for me.

Thanks!