# Is there another way to restart the sound system if pulseaudio/ALSA don't work?

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I was listening to music, and my sound suddenly went dead in all my applications. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, which uses pulseaudio, so I tried `sudo /etc/init.d/pulseaudio restart`, but nothing happened. According to `lsof | grep pcm`, nothing is using the soundcard at the moment, although I'm not entirely sure if [my source for that command](https://superuser.com/a/17315/126046) is applicable.

Is there a way another way to restart Ubuntu 12.04's sound system from the command line without rebooting the system?

Comment: This answer worked for me.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/15223/how-can-i-restart-pulseaudio-without-logout

Comment: I think the solution really depends on the computer you have and the ubuntu version installed on it. For me none of the 2 top answers worked.
**joeytwiddle's answer worked.** I have a **Lenovo Legion Y520** with **Ubuntu 16.04**: `sudo pm-suspend` is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: This is NOT an answer to the question, however, this page show up in the top when searching for how to fix the sound in Ubuntu 18 and 19. When having trouble with the motherboard built-in Intel soundcard, this solution has worked for me: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html Excerpt:
Ubuntu 18: add "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" at the end of the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf reboot Ubuntu 18, 19, 20. Kernel 5.3.0-41 and -42: Edit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf as root and add "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" Edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.c

Answer (score 529, accepted):

I've used `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` a couple of times, and it worked well. The first part kills pulseaudio, the second reloads ALSA. You don't need to restart pulseaudio, because it auto-restarts.

Comment: This helped to me to fix the issue 'no sound after suspend' I have suffered from for don't remember how long.

Comment: Ubuntu sometimes freezes for me and goes mental for about 10 minutes, after which it "wakes up" in a bit of a daze, including the sound not working. This fixed it!

Comment: This can also occur if the AudioThread is killed by the OOM killer thanks to misbehaving apps. The above worked perfectly.

Comment: Sometimes you might need to clear pulse config with "rm -R ~/.pulse*" before issuing any restart.

Comment: It works for me after my USB headphone stop to work.

Comment: This works when I plug laptop to TV via HDMI, it helps to show hdmi option in sound output so I can select it. I would like to be able to do this via GUI or trigger it once device is plugged to hdmi port.

Comment: I had to instead `sudo service pulseaudio stop && sudo alsa force-reload && sudo service pulseaudio start`.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: At my side I had to also re-plug the HDMI cable of the monitor to get sound working again.

Comment: This worked for me after the left headphones stopped working.

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04.2 when used HDMI audio and closed the lid on my DELL laptop. Audio in built in speakers or headphone didn't work until I ran this command! Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a pulseaudio service (17.04), so wasn't able to restart it (`Failed to restart pulseaudio.service: Unit pulseaudio.service not found.`) but I did have sound again after `/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start`.  I'm sure rebooting would've worked, too, but couldn't at the time.

Comment: Very good, i open my voice card to capture microphone. when finishing program with ctrl + c , and run program next time error: `client-l2cap: pcm_params.c:2290: snd_pcm_hw_refine: Assertion `pcm && params' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
`  and must be restarting system to use next time sound card, reloading voice module works great, you save me time.

Comment: `pulseaudio -k` saved my life ! no sudo needed

Comment: still work in 18.04

Comment: It seems that my soundcard hangs hard enough in Ubuntu 18.04 that I need to do this twice with a two second sleep in between. If I run it once or twice without a delay, it does not fix the audio. (My hardware is integrated audio on Asus P8H77-M PRO.)

Comment: `alsa` executable missing, any replacement?

Comment: after one entire year rebooting the machine, I found the solution. Really, I want to cry! Thank you :P (I don't know why I did not look for a solution before). It works for Xubuntu 18.04 too

Comment: Confirmed for the upcoming 20.4 Ubuntu. fixes HDMI audio corruption.

Comment: Yep. The HDMI audio on Ubuntu 20.04 dies after the screen saver goes on -- this command restores it (as does replugging the HDMI).

Comment: Solved the stream sounds going noisy bug for me.

Comment: still work in 21.10

Comment: In my case, plugging my HDMI cable into a different TV than normal is what caused me to lose audio. @Aitch' s answer is what did the trick for me `pulseaudio -k` which, as the man page for pulseaudio explains, will "kill an already running PulseAudio daemon of the calling user (Equivalent to sending a SIGTERM)."

Comment: I needed to launch: `pulseaudio --start` because I didn't have alsa binary

Comment: Running `pulseaudio -k` returns an error for me on the standard desktop edition of 22.04. I needed to run `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio-x11` instead.

Answer (score 70):

What I do when my sound doesn't work is

```
killall pulseaudio
```

and then I press <kbd>Alt + F2</kbd> and type in pulseaudio. It usually works for me.

Comment: What is the difference between this and `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`? The restart worked for me before, but today it did not and I needed to kill it (it seemed to automatically restart, when I typed pulseaudio in a terminal it errored that the daemon is already running).

Comment: There isn't much difference in practice. This answer relies on systemd detecting that pulseaudio has crashed and restarting it. Your version does this explicitly.

Answer (score 62):

Just for completeness, in newer Ubuntus versions that use systemd, I used this and it worked well:

`systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`

Comment: this answer fixed my problem

Comment: This is the way to restart PulseAudio in Ubuntu 20. Thank you!

Comment: This, along with killing/restarting Alsa, allowed me to get the audio working on my Acer Swift 3 (Ryzen 4700U) under Kubuntu 20.10.

Comment: This answer is very useful since pulseaudio won't function properly after a session change (or CTRL-ALT-BACKSPACE) in ubuntu 20.04

Comment: still works in 2023 with an up-to date ubuntu

Comment: Looks like the service is now named `pulseaudio-x11`. Running `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio-x11` worked on my system running the standard desktop edition of version 22.04.

Answer (score 29):

In my case there were nasty messages in `kern.log` / `dmesg`:

```
sound hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: invalid ELD buf size -1
```

The solution was simply to suspend and resume the machine!

```
$ sudo pm-suspend
```

Comment: i don't know what was going on, I also had a mike problem, reinstalled pulseaudio and alsa packages, but the `sudo pm-suspend` trick did it....

Comment: Battery died on my Dell, did all the above, tried this as a last resort and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Same thing happened here - after battery died, headphones did not work after next boot. `pm-suspend` fixed it.

Comment: In the last Wifislax(64 2.0)livecd -intoram. The 'mixer' dissapeared and OS sound got muted after all I've tryed all above none worked only this.

Comment: Does someone able to explain this behaiour?

Comment: This works better than pulseaudio -k in centoos7

Comment: Still observed on 18.04.

Comment: it works in 16.04 with me

Comment: Solved the same issue in 22.04 with this, audio was missing after locking and unlocking the screen.

Answer (score 11):

For the new multimedia framework **Pipewire**, [which became the default since Ubuntu 22.10](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/05/ubuntu-22-10-makes-pipewire-default), restart the Pipewire services.

```sh
❯ systemctl --user restart pipewire.service

# if the above is not enough, try
❯ systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse.service
```

Comment: You should be more clear about what do you mean by "newer version"?

Comment: @s.ouchene Thanks, it shouldn't be a "newer version" :-) I have rephrased it.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same symptom: sound suddenly died (after trying to use Audacity, in my case). The OP didn't mention he was/wasn't wearing headphones, which was my case. I tried all options here and, when going to Preferences and changing to HDMI or Speaker output worked, but switching to Headphones didn't work (no sound). I then tried to **unplug and re-plug the headphones** and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue with a USB audio device that would sometimes when booting the machine, not connect properly leaving me without audio until a reboot. If you are someone who is having the same issue but with a USB audio device then I recommend the following which fixed it for me:

```bsh
sudo rmmod xhci_pci && sudo rmmod xhci_hcd && sudo modprobe xhci_pci xhci_hcd
```

None of the other answers would fix it and I assume that came down to the USB device not registering properly on boot. This simply reboots the USB devices. Note: you should only run all commands at once, running `sudo rmmod xhci_hcd` alone will disable all USB devices e.g., your keyboard, meaning the remaining commands cannot be run.

I will be honest and say that I doubt that the `xchi_pci` part is necessary, so if someone is more knowledgeable regarding this please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

For me on MX Linux 23 (Debian 12.1) the following worked:

```
sudo alsactl -F restore
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked inside the folder to see if pulseaudio was available in init.d, try replacing pulse audio with alsa-utils

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping + waking up the PC is the only thing that's fixed it for me (other than a reboot). I'm using bluetooth audio w/ the notoriously buggy intel ax20x.