# No sound in Ubuntu 13.04 64bit in dual boot with Windows 7 Pro 64bit

Tags: 13.04, sound, pulseaudio, rhythmbox

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 64bit on Windows 7 Pro 64bit enabling myself the service of dual boot.

I am facing a problem of "No Sound" in any of the player even after installing all of the updates and the gstreamer drivers requested by the Rhythmbox.

I tried installing pulseaudio drivers once more after purge remove but still no result.

Can someone please help?

---

I found some odd problem regarding the sound on Ubuntu 13.04.

My motherboard Intel DG43RK has 10.1 channel i.e various ports for various sound devices.

The sound is only working in the front port which comes by default attached onto the CPU cabinet and not on any of the ports of the motherboard.

How can this be solved?

Comment: does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230888/is-there-another-way-to-restart-ubuntu-12-04s-sound-system-if-pulseaudio-alsa-d) help?

Comment: No I am getting the following     'dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.'

Comment: I am also getting Unable to lock the administration directory(.....), is another proc using it? when I use apt-get install pulseaudio

Comment: regarding "`dpkg` was interrupted", try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as advised. Is `synaptic` or `update manager` running?

Comment: No none of them are running and I also ran the sudo dpkg --configure -a

Comment: And now the sound icon has gone missing from my top status bar, And also the keyboard's multimedia key which governs the mute operation is also not showing any message after pressing it.

Comment: Please someone, it is getting frustrating without sound on Ubuntu, can someone provide a solution.

Comment: [this](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) fits nicely with what you have described

Comment: Actually that link was the place which I visited before posting this question.

Comment: I tried the first method but no result and second method showed no result either as the text file was already stated as RUN=no

Answer (score 0):

Just try it once:

There is a sound icon on the top-right bar. Click on it -> 'Sound Settings' -> 'Hardware' Tab -> 'Settings for the selected device: Profile:' and chose some different options from the selection list. There is a button 'Test Speakers', you can test your sound when ever you chose different options.

Reply if it doesn't work..

Comment: No the sound icon is also invisible.

Comment: you can also go to sound setting from 'All Settings' -> 'Sound'.
just right click on desktop and chose 'Change Desktop Background' -> 'All Setting' tab. Just try it once.

Comment: Tried it, it is working in a odd way, if Headphone is on the analog output is OFF. Why is this happening? Why can't I keep both ON at once?