# ubuntu 14.04 sound issue suddenly stopped working

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio

when I started my computer this morning my sound was not working i searched google and found the [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462503/ubuntu-14-04-sound-suddenly-stopped-working-reboot-did-not-fix) topic (second answer)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
And force reload Alsa again:

sudo alsa force-reload
```

I did that didn't work in fact I lost that setting panel from that left app tray.

I went on and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457619/sound-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04) and I tried the following command too

```
Step one: Reinstall alsa-utils

sudo apt-get install alsa-utils --reinstall

Step two: Download and install alsa-lib

Here is a link to version 1.0.25-4(the stable version)

Extract the archive and run the following code in the extracted directory

./configure && make

Then

sudo make install
```

that too but nothing is happening please help I need my computer in working order, please help

Regards

Muhammad

Comment: Look (or paste in your question )  this command result to see if soundcard is detected :        "aplay -l "           If detected ,  run  alsamixer in a terminal : you should see faders

Answer (score -1):

after the upgrade, in AlsaMixer my Automute was enabled, I've  disabled it and sound is back

[image]