# Sound issue in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: sound, alsa, hp

When I first install Ubuntu in my notebook I can heard the sound in both headphone and also in system speaker. But now I am not hear any sound in my laptop. Whenever I launch the command sudo apt-get updates, sudo apt-get install updates, sudo apt-get upgrades;

Sound issues occur each time I launched these command or installed other software in Ubuntu.

I have also go through each step to solve my problem also resolved the sound issues when I trouble shoot the sound issues using this link : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting.

But again I launch above mentioned command in my terminal for updates and again facing sound issues this time I am not able to troubleshoot my problem. I am giving some screenshots which help to understand my problem below with my configuration.

My Laptop configuration is:

1. Laptop - HP 240 G4O
2. Ram - 8 Gb
3. OS - Ubuntu 14.o4

It used to open before the issues but now it doesn't show

```
hp@hp-HP-240-G4-Notebook-PC:~$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory


hp@hp-HP-240-G4-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d70 (rev 21)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8131
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 141
Memory at a1228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at a1210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

hp@hp-HP-240-G4-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...

hp@hp-HP-240-G4-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo aplay -l
[sudo] password for hp: 
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
hp@hp-HP-240-G4-Notebook-PC:~$ pacmd
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
```

```
list-sinks 
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 1000
    volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 15 KiB
    max rewind: 15 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 12
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

[image]

I am not able to fix it and now it is out of my mind. I am new for Ubuntu but I tried my best. If any other information is needed please let me know.

Comment: if sound problem is caused by an upgraded kernel, you can choose previous kernel by pressing escape key in early boot, just after bios, then choose previous kernel using  the boot menu

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty common issue.

Please try the following:

### Fix Alternative #1

Try reinstalling Alsa and Pulse audio in the following manner:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

And force reload Alsa again:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

### Fix Alternative #2

Open the terminal and edit speech-dispatcher file by using the following command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

In here, change `RUN=yes` to `RUN=no`

Reboot.

Let me know if it have worked for you.

Source: [It's FOSS](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)

If it doesn't help you can try other solutions [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462503/ubuntu-14-04-sound-suddenly-stopped-working-reboot-did-not-fix)