# Sound issue in 18.04

Tags: sound, 18.04

In my system I can hear sound only from here while modifying it in settings

[image]

and occasionally system popup/error sounds.

And sound is not coming from any other videos, songs, Youtube, test speakers etc.,

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794226/sound-issue-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts) and some other, but no use. Why I can able to hear from that and no where else except while modifying output volume?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. No program could output audio, except the system settings speaker test.

I was able to fix it by **deleting the config files** in `~/.config/pulse` and then restarting pulseaudio with `pulseaudio --kill`. It should restart immediately and recreate the config files with what seems to be default settings.

After that audio worked again :)