# How to restore sound in Video Player, Rhythmbox, and VLC?

Tags: sound, vlc, rhythmbox, video-player

Two days ago in my Ubuntu 18.04, at once sound disappeared in Video Player as well as in VLC player and the Rhythmbox. How to improve that issue?

Comment: When I watch YUTUBE etc. there is sound normaly. When I tried to reboot Linux 18.04 in recovery mode, it saids: no such file or directory /lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu:

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/462503) might help.

Comment: Problem with sound is solved by installing other media players mpv Media Player, GNOME MPV, foobar etc. Above mentioned VLC media player, Videos and Rhitmbox have no sound yet.