# Not hearing sound on my laptop with my os Ubuntu

Tags: gnome

I don't hear any sound from my os Ubuntu on my lap hp 15 notebook pc .
what is its reason ?

Comment: the sound icon in the taskbar above,click there and see it is mute or not.

Comment: The mute is not ticked!

Comment: Increase the volume to see the sound is not coming or not,then see if your system is recognizing your sound card or not by "sudo aplay -l"

Comment: try http://askubuntu.com/a/230893/283843

Comment: How about headphones, do they work for you?!

Answer (score 2):

First step, just to verify, check if the sound is not muted. Once you verify this, go to
**Sound Settings:**

[image]

In the Sound Settings, you’ll find that you have practically nothing here except a dummy output. Quite frustrating. It means that your sound card is not even recognized. Puff!

[image]

No worries. The one shot solution which fixed the sound problem for me on my Intel powered Dell Inspiron N4010 is to **force reload Alsa**. To do that, use the following command in terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

The output will be like this.

[image]

You may think that it is hanged or still in processing but it takes only couple of seconds. You can simply close it afterwards by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Now, you need to **reboot** your computer. If at the next start up, you hear the login sound at the lock screen, you know it worked like a charm.

[image]

#### First Alternate method to fix no sound in Ubuntu 14.04:

If the above problem did not fix it for you, try reinstalling Alsa and Pulse audio in the following manner:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

And force reload Alsa again:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Restart and enjoy the world of sound, again.

#### Second Alternate method to fix no sound in Ubuntu 14.04:

Open the terminal and edit speech-dispatcher file by using the following command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

In here, change **RUN=yes** to **RUN=no**

Reboot and enjoy sound.

[[source]](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)