# Dell XPS 13 9343 Ubuntu 16.04 NO AUDIO

Tags: drivers, sound

I did a dual-boot of 16.04 Ubuntu and windows 10. for a couple of days my system worked fine but now I have no sound in both ubuntu and windows.

After reading the forums, I tried to install pulse-audio but I don't see any output other than HDMI.

Can anyone help on how to get the drivers?

```
$ lspci -nnk
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Broadwell-U Audio Controller [1028:0665]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: broadwellrt286 [broadwell-rt286], device 0: System Playback/Capture (*) []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: broadwellrt286 [broadwell-rt286], device 1: Offload0 Playback (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: broadwellrt286 [broadwell-rt286], device 2: Offload1 Playback (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


$ pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo-extra2 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

David, I am not sure why but in my alsamixer or anything it says that I have no devices connected to my laptop except for the HDMI, which I do not want to adjust, I just want to be able to hear sounds from my laptop.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Comment: If both Windows and Linux are affected by the same issue it's probably a BIOS setting or an altogether faulty device, both of which have nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: I have made sure the audio is on from the BIOS. I also find it hard to believe that it's a coincidence that the audio just stops working just days after I dualbooted because my machine has been running solid for over a year with no issues.

Comment: I even tried to download audio drivers and reinstalled them from windows, and still no luck. Really, ANY help will be appreciated I really want to listen to music while I code!

Comment: Update. I got the sound working by downloaidng the realtek drivers but my ubuntu still doesn't output any sounds.  Good news is that when I do aplay -l, I get a card 1 now. It's written above.

Comment: How did you install the driver?

Comment: I downloaded it on realtek's website from my windows partition and just ran the .exe. But I am sad to say even my windows doesn't get sound anymore after i restarted my machine. it just seems very unstable for some reason.

Comment: Another update: Weird but a temporary fix to the problem I have found is that if I boot into windows first, then power down and turn on linux my sound works. but i have no sound recognized on windows or if i just turn on linux straight away... very annoying please help!!

Comment: If you haven't already, could you please turn off *Fast Boot* in Windows so it shuts down completely before you (re-)boot into Ubuntu? Sometimes Windows drivers leave device firmware in a state that renders them unusable to dual-booted operating systems. Conversely the same driver might then be confused if a different operating system tried to claim the same device.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, specifically after Windows went into hibernation (Fastboot is off). Pushing the following command into terminal, [as described in this Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230888/is-there-another-way-to-restart-the-sound-system-if-pulseaudio-alsa-dont-work), solves the issue: `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`

Answer (score 1):

Check if audio device is not disabled in BIOS (not sure but probably: "System configuration" -> "Audio").

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/640850)

Comment: I don't see why this "does not provide an answer". Installing alsamixer will not change Windows behavior. Especially that Dell BIOS have tendency to change some settings on it own (e.g. XPS 9350 with <1.4 versions). It legitimate question/advice to check BIOS settings.

Comment: It's a good comment but not an answer if you have to ask OP to check for something first.