# No sound! Deleted /etc/pulse directory

Tags: 17.10

After having some issues with sound i decided to delete the whole `/etc/pulse` directory, thinking that they are just temporary files. 
I *deleted the files from terminal* so I cannot restore them from trash. Now i have no sound, how do i fix it?

I tried:

```
sudo apt remove pulseaudio
sudo apt install pulseaudio
```

Answer (score -1):

Did reinstalling pulseaudio restore the files to `/etc/pulse`? The next step would be to check if pulseaudio is running.

```
pulseaudio --check
echo $?
```

0 = running

Or try: `ps -ef | grep pulse`

The default configuration is for pulseaudio to try to restart itself whenever it quits but it could be running into errors when starting.

This might be helpful: [How can I restart pulseaudio without logout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15223/how-can-i-restart-pulseaudio-without-logout)

Comment: Reinstalling did not restore the files. Also pulseaudio is not running and it does not start up. Thanks for your time!