# No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 22.04, pipewire

Problem: No sound after upgrade from ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 (using development release) both built in speakers and hdmi output.

Some background: running on ubuntu 21.04, I noticed that my sound was not so great so I did some research for sound and I finally managed to get better sound using pipewire with easyeffects. My guess is that I have to either remove this setup or adjust it for ubuntu 22.04 but I cant find the config settings anymore which I changed earlier.

Some info regarding my setup:

```
➜  ~ pactl info | grep '^Server Name'                
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.48)

➜  ~ inxi -SMA                                           
System:
  Host: BEWELIN001L Kernel: 5.15.0-25-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.0 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Notebook product: PC5x_7xHP_HR_HS v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Notebook model: PC5x_7xHP_HR_HS serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: INSYDE v: 1.07.08 date: 09/07/2021
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-H HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-25-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

[image: no-output-device-listed-ubuntu-22.04]

Sound settings just shows "dummy output" in the output device dropdown

[image]

Any ideas how to get this fixed?

Comment: to clarify: did you upgrade-install to 22.04, or did you fresh-install 22.04 ?

Comment: I upgraded using command: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` 

I have now tried: `sudo apt-get remove pipewire` after which my whole system went out and doesnt boot anymore. So Im not downloading the iso on a flash drive to try to repair my system or do a fresh install.

Comment: "...Im not downloading..."  I suggest you download the ISO and fresh-install from it.  I know many purists think an upgrade-install is preferable: but in my history, such upgrades create conflicts, and these can take weeks to resolve. A fresh-install is usually no more than 30 minutes, and avoids huge frustrations and wasted time.

Comment: @robgrune oops thats a typo. It should be "I am now downloading". I am by far not a purist, I just want it to work :D 5 minutes left for the download to finish.

Comment: A fresh install of 22.04 fixed my sound issue.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for informing the community.

Comment: I had the same issue after upgrading. What helped me is a complete shutdown. Simply rebooting doesn't work for some reason.
I got the tip from [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/sl4b4v/ubuntu_2110_no_sound_dummy_output/hw9no8a) on Reddit.

Comment: indeed, rebooting was not working to find my audio devices. A reel shutdown worked!

Comment: I have the same problem. Sound worked perfectly on 21.10 but not on 22.04

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: Like you I tried `sudo apt-get remove pipewire` and it uninstalls gnome.  Following up with `sudo apt-install gnome` and it looks like it's reinstalling pulseaudio and pipewire.  It's a big fat install.  This may be my last post on this install.

Comment: @ThdK I also did a fresh install of 22.04 and it worked for a while, but now I get "dummy output" again.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I had the same issue after upgrading from 21.10.

I was able to fix this by running:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

For some reason pipewire-media-session was no longer picking up `/etc/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio`

Source: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/pipewire-media-session/pipewire-media-session_0.4.1-2ubuntu1/changelog

Comment: This also worked for me when upgrading from 21.10

Comment: Not working for me. How did you debug this?

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: Same solution worked in Debian Testing (bookworm) too

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (5.11.0-41-generic)

Comment: works for me (on Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid running on kernel 5.19.0.2), thank you very much

Comment: Debian bookworm too. Works!

Comment: Work for me too! I upgraded my OS from ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10 (beta) on Oct 16 2022 and encountered the same problem, and this works for me perfectly.

Comment: Worked for me!  I upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10 (release) on Oct 21 2022 and had no sound, and this fixed it.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: worked upgrading from 22.04 to 22.10

Comment: didn't work on 22.04.2

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped, with installing pulseaudio (it wasn't there). Honestly, I don't know why they do this, and what is wrong with them.

Comment: The first time it worked for me, but when sound disappeared second time it didn't. Helped sudo alsa force-reload

Comment: Had to do this after installing pipewire on Ubuntu 22.04 for it to see my audio devices.

Answer (score 12):

I was having the same issue in **Ubuntu 20.04**. I tried to restart but it didn't help. Finally, I got the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15223/how-can-i-restart-pulseaudio-without-having-to-logout).

Just restart `pulseaudio` service it will start working again.

Kill the running instance:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Start pulseaudio again as a daemon:

```
pulseaudio -D
```

Please note that it fixed my `Dummy Output` problem on **Ubuntu 20.04**. A try is always worth giving.

Comment: I got the same problem and when I tried pulseaudio -D I got this error:
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.

Comment: worse, in my case, `pulseaudio -k` made my wired headset disappear from the list of output audio devices. Now the sound comes out of my HDMI monitor!

Comment: Oh! That worked for me. Actually I only had to do the `pulseaudio -k` and it auto-restarted within a split second and everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

OPTION 1

Open the terminal.

- Type alsamixer and press the Enter key.
- You will see the some output in your terminal.
- Use the left and right arrow keys to select a volume control. and use up and down arrow keys to increase and decrease volume levels for
  each control.
- Note: the currently selected item is shown in red. If mixer control
  is muted, “MM” appears below the volume bar. You can unmute control
  by pressing the m key. This changes “MM” to “OO.”
- To exit alsamixer, press the Esc key.

OPTION 2

Run the following on the terminal and restart your system

```
$ alsaloop

$ sudo alsa force-reload
```

reboot your computer, and test your sound again to see if it is working.

OPTION 3

If none of the above solutions work for you, try reinstalling ALSA and PulseAudio that must fix the problem for you. Open your terminal, and enter the following commands: sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base

sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Comment: Option #1 worked, thanks!

(Just upgraded to 22.04, none of the other suggestions with higher vote counts worked for me)

Comment: I am so glad it did! @Diederik

Comment: It worked. thank you

Answer (score 2):

after couple days of struggling this reddit [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/m7yc6j/comment/grek9iv/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) worked for me

as the answer suggest remove pipewire config files then reinstall pipewire, pipewire-pulse, and pipewire-media-session

> 1. Remove all the configuration files in /etc/pipewire (sudo mv
>    /etc/pipewire /tmp)
> 2. Reinstall pipewire, pipewire-pulse, and pipewire-media-session (sudo
>    pacman -S pipewire pipewire-pulse pipewire-media-session)
> 3. Enable and start the relevant services (systemctl --user enable
>    pipewire pipewire-pulse pipewire-media-session) and (systemctl
>    --user restart pipewire pipewire-pulse pipewire-media-session). After that, my devices appeared as usual and I was back in business.

Comment: confirm, worked for me on kubuntu 22.04. Appreciate!

Comment: confirm, this fixed my Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many things after the upgrade to 22.04 and nothing seemed to work, and what I noticed (in my case), is that the kernel was not using the snd_hda_intel driver and therefor couldn't see/load the soundcard while lspci was still showing the soundcard.

I tried several of the options found and what did work for me what eventually the last option found on this page:

https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

which was actually saying to add the following to the alsa-base.conf (/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf) and reboot:

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

after the reboot I finally had audio again!

Comment: This worked to get speakers back for me - but no microphone detected.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Pipewire was no help to me, but I needed to install some missing components of it, as detailed here:
[Problem with sound in Ubuntu 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436904/problem-with-sound-in-ubuntu-22-10)