# Audio problems on upgrade

Tags: upgrade, sound, hdmi, 21.10, 22.04

Consistently getting audio issues when upgrading 21.10 to 22.04 (*not* dev build, *no* 3dParty/Secure, several flavors: Mate, Ubuntu, Kubuntu): Dummy output device inserted, pavucontrol shows no HW.

When installing clean on same box (same HW) never any issues. Both HDMI and built-in audio are detected and available reboot after reboot.

Done almost every bit of troubleshooting using askubuntu posts going back to 16.04, when this problem seems to have started. My conclusion is that there is something that needs to be ripped out and/or problems emanating from modprobe.d/alsa-mixer.conf reads and writes. Wish I could just pull out every bit of audio "plumbing" and start fresh on these particular upgrades! Any way to do just that? Or disable the dummy device, it is of no earthly use to me.

This is a laptop that I connect to a TV, dual-boot w/Windows 11 if that helps. HP Evo x360 that I keep the lid closed, don't use 2.5mm jack.

Alsamixer shows (on a "fresh" install):
`Card: HDA Intel PCH Chip: Realtek ALC295`

alsamixer (on upgrade install):

```
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0' ALSA lib
> conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum
> returned error: No such file or directory ALSA lib
> confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings ALSA lib
> conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned
> error: No such file or directory ALSA lib
> confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name ALSA lib
> conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned
> error: No such file or directory ALSA lib
> conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or
> directory ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL
> default cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

lspci shows (on upgrade install):

`00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)`

Comment: having the same issue today after upgrading from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, did you find the solution to this?

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it with the answer from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04