# volume keys are not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 22.04, volume-control

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04. Earlier volume increase, decrease and mute were working just fine, however since yesterday I cannot increase/decrease the volume from the keyboard keys. Also, Please have a look at the below image. The output doesn't show any device.

[image]

Comment: It depends on hardware. There is no information in the question to tell anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04)

Answer (score 1):

Adam's solution works for me [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404159/1594035)

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

Comment: That one did not work for me, however, the one where I restart pulse audio like so: `pulseaudio -k` worked at once.