# Upgrade from 21.04 to 22.04, audio lost (Dummy output only)

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, 22.04

SOLUTION (FIXED):
So I tried to install 22.04 from scratch instead of trying to figure out what is the issue and fix it. Downloaded the image, made usb and booted. Just to find out that there is some bug related to grub and 22.04 is currently not possible to install.

I thought I had a good run with Ubuntu (5+years) and it's time to go back home with debian. So I did.
Might come back if Ubuntu makes it possible to install and maybe even reinstall ;)

=> Audio works now (debian11)

---

Did the usual do-release-upgrade 2-3days ago 'cause I like riding bleeding edge blind and reckless.

Now there's no audio since the upgrade.

I can see the card:

---

> ```
> > jyrki@kekkonen:~$ sudo inxi -SMA 
> > System:
> >   Host: kekkonen Kernel: 5.15.0-30-generic x86_64 bits: 64
> >     Desktop: GNOME 42.0 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) 
> > Machine:
> >   Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: Z390 M v: N/A serial: N/A   
> >   Mobo: Gigabyte model: Z390 M-CF v: x.x serial: N/A
> >     UEFI: American Megatrends v: F6j date: 01/19/2021 
> > Audio:   
> >   Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: N/A   
> >   Device-2: NVIDIA GM206 High Definition Audio driver: N/A
> >   Device-3: Logitech Webcam C270 type: USB driver: N/A   
> >   Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-30-generic running: yes
> >   Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
> >   Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
> ```

---

Card is recognized by kernel but no driver, so essentially aplay fails:

```
> jyrki@kekkonen:~$ aplay -l
> aplay: device_list:274: äänikortteja ei löytynyt...
```

---

Nothing in dmesg:

> ```
> > jyrki@kekkonen:~$ sudo dmesg|grep -e 'audio\|snd\|intel' 
> > [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/BOOT/ubuntu_841rk4@/vmlinuz-5.15.0-30-generic root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_841rk4 ro quiet splash intel_iommu=on,igfx_off vt.handoff=1 
> > [    0.029593] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/BOOT/ubuntu_841rk4@/vmlinuz-5.15.0-30-generic root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_841rk4 ro quiet splash intel_iommu=on,igfx_off vt.handoff=1 
> > [    2.964560] intel_pstate: Intel P-state driver initializing
> > [    2.964978] intel_pstate: Disabling energy efficiency optimization
> > [    2.964978] intel_pstate: HWP enabled
> > [    2.999704] intel_pmc_core INT33A1:00:  initialized
> > [ 105.156978] audit: type=1400 audit(1652119587.700:77): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/sys/bus/snd_seq/devices/" pid=4824 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
> ```

---

So (I think) it's no pavucontrol, PipeWire, Alsa nor PulseAudio -issue, nor it's an issue with snd-hda-intel because I've (kinda) understood that such does not exist with 5.15. kernel when dealing with Cannon Lake anymore? Should be sof-something and did check, my system has links to signed-cnl-version of the driver:

```
/lib/firmware/intel/sof/intel-signed/sof-cnl.r
```

Trivial apt update && apt upgrade has been done.
Tried all of less than 2 months old tricks suggested here @ AskUbuntu related to DummyOutput.

So I'm kinda stucked now.

Not very keen to dive into compile-build-fail -path of creating my own kernel outside of official distro. I think this is something less difficult, just don't see the obvious I guess.

### Appreciate your guidance, what ever it may be.

Jyrki

Comment: 22.04 is not "bleeding edge"-- it is an LTS release. However the upgrade you attempted is not supported. First, 21.04 is already past EOL, so there is no longer a supported upgrade path away from this release.  Also, it is never supported to skip over releases when upgrading. The only supported upgrade from 21.04 was to 21.10 and that became unsupported when 21.04 became EOL in January 2022. I suggest that you reinstall the system. Don't forget that you need to perform a release upgrade to the next release *before* your system becomes EOL.

Comment: Please see: [How to... upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815) and [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34430) and [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/16366)

Comment: I'd suggest checking your details; as a `do-release-upgrade` on a 21.04 system would upgrade you to a Ubuntu 21.10 system, as it can **only** upgrade to the next release OR if you're on a LTS release; the next LTS.  Ubuntu 21.04 was **not** a LTS so it's upgrades only advanced to Ubuntu 21.10.  Your question either contains errors or missing details that may explain problems; what you said can't be done.

Comment: ok, how can I do that?

Comment: Ok, ignore adjectives. Problem is that there is no audio. According to this, it is 22.04: jyrki@kekkonen:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

Comment: I assumed it was 21.something that is why I put 21.04. According to Nmath it could have been something else, propably. Still, no audio with 22.04LTS.

Comment: This was the 1st time this system suggested to do the release upgrade. Typically such thing comes up way before EOL. Ok, will wipe and install from scratch.

Comment: This is not a solved problem in Ubuntu. Debian, maybe. But saying it is FIXED is incorrect

Comment: Debian won't have fixed it... it'll be related to the kernel, if 21.04 was being used that's 5.11 kernel contrasted with 5.15 used by default with 22.04 LTS... Debian uses a different kernel regardless of *unstated* release.. issue unrelated to Ubuntu but hardware & kernel (thus *kernel modules* which are commonly called *drivers*.. not alsa/pa/pipewire user-end but closer to kernel)... Unless using Debian *bookworm/sid* it'll be an older kernel thus closer to older Ubuntu 21.04...

Answer (score 9):

[No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04/1404159#1404159?newreg=b7e9c36b79544d159a8b77224dec8ecf)

I was able to fix this by running:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

For some reason pipewire-media-session was no longer picking up `/etc/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio`

Source: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/pipewire-media-session/pipewire-media-session_0.4.1-2ubuntu1/changelog

Comment: After reinstalling pulse an alsa without success, this is was the only answer that solve my issue.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. Still without sound and Settings shows only the dummy output device.

Comment: +1 This worked for me after sound was lost when upgrading from 22.04 to 22.10.

Comment: Almost five months later and still no solution! This really sucks! If I want sound, I need to use one of my Android devices?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by changing kernel from 5.13.0-44 to 5.15.0-40. After all sound problems are gone
ciao albert

Comment: My kernel is the latest version. And my audio was borked after the upgrade.

Comment: having a slightly newer kernel after the upgrade today and still having sound issues...

Comment: hey, what's newest kernels number? my uname -r tells me: 5.15.0-43-generic and sound works. ciao albert

Comment: kernel 6.0.2 works all right, 6.0.3 does not (Dummy Output only) :(

Comment: I had similar problem. Bad bootable disk was selected in bios and it started old grup. Weirdly enough, it started new ubuntu, bud with old kernel. Selecting correct boot device in BIOS helped.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off Over-Amplification in sound settings.  That solved the no sound issue for me.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. Please provide some details on how you did this, and what the effect was so that people can try this for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall OSS4-base, it blacklists most audio drivers at boot. It fixed my issue afterwards both Pipewire and PulseAudio worked.