# Distorted audio on USB speakerphone on Ubuntu 22.04, worked fine first but broke in system update

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, 22.04

I have Ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop with I9-10885H and NVidia GTX1650. I have installed nvidia-drivers-510 proprietary drivers. I am using Jabra SPEAK 510 USB speakerphone for audio.

After initial 22.04 installation **audio worked fine**.

Then I **upgraded the packages with Software Updater**. This broke the audio with Jabra. Sometimes it works OK for some time, but at some point **audio becomes distorted**, with lots of static etc. Example clip (sorry, low volume): https://sndup.net/cm3m/

When this happens, USB keyboard also starts to act weird: single press to for example j key sometimes "sticks" and produces jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj.... until another key is pressed.

I think this dpkg.log contains the upgraded packages that broke audio: https://pastebin.com/KCvtua2r

Laptop's own speakers and the headphone connection work fine.

I see many tempting answers like https://askubuntu.com/a/1404159 but I am hesitant about trying those without understanding at all what's going on and what the fixes do.

[image: sound options]

Comment: Does it happen in both outputs (digital and analog)?

Comment: Yes it does.

Weird, now I am running about 15 minutes with good audio. Could it have been this phenomenon: https://askubuntu.com/a/1404153 - I only did a proper shutdown (or at least dual booted to windows) now and it feels it may have helped.

I will know more after tomorrow's workday, wrapping up now for today.

Comment: Yes, it could have been. And if you're dual-booting with Windows disabling Windows' Fast Startup Feature is a must. Among other issues it can mess with the hardware initialization.

Comment: Seems to be related to restarts and maybe dual booting to windows. Powering off/on before boot seems to improve things https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0 Unfortunately there's no option to disable fast startup in my win 10 even when I click "Change settings that are currently unavailable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distorted audio seems to happen more rarely (but still sometimes) as long as I do a cold startup, ie. don't restart my laptop but instead fully shutdown and then start it.