# No sound output or microphone input on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, microphone

I am facing a problem with my Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Over night I simply cannot change the volume with the shortcuts on my keyboard. So I go to the Settings menu and try to change something there, but nothing happens, in fact, it tells me that there isn't even an output nor an input device. Changing the System Volume through the bar does visually happen, but it doesn't change the volume.
What should I do?
Thank you in advance.
[image: Here is the output]

[image: and here is the input]

Comment: I had the same problem and this comment on reddit helped me https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/wsgw52/comment/ikyt95n/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very similar to [No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04)

that I could solve with:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

(credits go to https://askubuntu.com/users/1156299/adam)

Comment: Hello, I am having the same problem again, only that this time it tells me this when I try your solution:

Failed to restart pipewire-session-manager.service: Unit pipewire-session-manager.service not found.

Answer (score 0):

If add file don't solve this problem. I reinstall drivers

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

and restart system

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).