# Only dummy audio on laptop when updating from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10

Tags: sound, 22.10

My laptop doesn't recognize my sound card and have only dummy audio. When running `inxi -A` I get this:

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: N/A
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP107GL High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-21-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes
```

I tried suggested solutions, like installing WirePlumber or restarting PulseAudio, but they don't work.

Comment: Same here. Really need to get the audio working.

Comment: And the volume keys on my laptop isn't working either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04)

Answer (score 12):

[link to a thread on linux.org with the same problem](https://www.linux.org/threads/dummy-output-ubu-22-10-please-help-im-devastated.41066/)

```
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio

systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

I had the same problem and followed the steps from the link.

Comment: This didn't work for me, still on dummy audio :(

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks!

Comment: @Noobmaster69 what's the output of `inxi -xxz --audio`

Comment: Thx , work for me  ubuntu 22.10

Comment: This work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04)

I had the same problem and followed the steps from the above link

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
sudo systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
sudo reboot now
```

Solved !!!!

Comment: I got the following error when trying the restart command: 'Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)'

Comment: @PepeAlvarez I had the same error. Did you figure out how to solve it?

Comment: @demid I did not. Only thing that actually worked was to make use of an external speaker, which I enabled the Bluetooth properly from some code I found here. I tried so many things that I lost track of what I did though.

Comment: @PepeAlvarez thanks. I had a similar experience. Had to re-install OS in the end to make everything work

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem but for AMD card:

```
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-21-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes
```

For me it helps to boot to the 22.04 latest kernel

```
Linux tsebo-T14 5.15.0-52-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 13 08:03:55 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After booting ubuntu with 5.15.0-52-generic, sound drivers are back and working as expected.

Comment: I booted with `5.15.0-52-generic` but sound still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire pipewire-pulse
```

and check if you have file: /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d

if no such file then reinstall this:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install pipewire-media-session
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this(if you need to auto start pulseaudio each time after reboot);

1. Remove Pipewire using `sudo apt remove pipewire`
2. Enable Pulseaudio using `systemctl --user enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket`
3. Now start pulseaudio using `pulseaudio --start` or `systemctl --user start pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket`
4. Now do a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jurij Pitulja, this works for me

systemctl --user restart pipewire pipewire-pulse

sudo apt --reinstall install pipewire-media-session

Answer (score 0):

I am running 23.04 and audio usually works, one day I booted up and there was no audio device just dummy.

```
$ inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: jacob-rog23 Kernel: 6.2.0-27-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME v: 44.3 Distro: Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ROG Strix G614JU_G614JU v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: G614JU v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: G614JU.317 date: 07/12/2023
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.2.0-27-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
```

This command fixed it for me:

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire.service
```