# No audio after upgrade to 22.10

Tags: upgrade, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 22.10

Today morning I did an upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10. However, after the upgrade I've noticed that there is no audio output from my device. I did a reboot and then the internet stopped working. However, there was an additional device called **dummy network** in `nmcli device` which I removed to get the internet back and running.

To fix audio, whenever I visited sound settings there were no output devices except there was only an option named **dummy output**.

I thought it would be something with pulse audio, hence I used `systemctl --user start pulseaudio` to enable sound. But the problem is, I have to do it manually after each reboot.

Can somebody help me to get `pulseaudio` to start automatically upon startup?

Output for `systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service`;

```
○ pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; preset:>
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ○ pulseaudio.socket
```

Comment: What kernel are you using?

Comment: @David I'm using 5.19.0-23-generic kernel

Comment: Just as a test look and see in grub when you boot under advance options what kernels are available.

Comment: 5.19.0-23 and 5.15.0-52

Comment: OK so on boot choose the 5.15 kernel and see if the problems persist.

Comment: @David yes booted on both kernel and problem still exists ;(

Comment: I suggest then filing a bug report. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

Comment: @David Yeah I will report it. But the most annoying fact is I have to start `pulseaudio` every time I reboot, but once its started it does not stop no matter how many time I kill it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only dummy audio on laptop when updating from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436452/only-dummy-audio-on-laptop-when-updating-from-ubuntu-22-04-to-22-10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the issue.

According to a new article by [fosshub](https://www.fosslinux.com/81749/features-in-ubuntu-22-10-and-how-to-upgrade.htm), under features of the new Ubuntu 22.10 it states that;
*Pipewire is introduced as the default audio server*

Hence `pulseaudio` was replaced by `pipewire` after the upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10.

So I simply removed pipewire using;

```
sudo apt remove pipewire
```

And then I enabled both `pulseaudio.service` and `pulseaudio.socket` using

```
systemctl --user --now enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
```

In my case it was already enabled. I just had to start it, to start pulse audio

```
systemctl --user start pulseaudio.service
systemctl --user start pulseaudio.socket
```

or

```
pulseaudio --start
```

Now it automatically starts after log in.

Comment: I had to reboot, but that's the only solution that worked, after upgrading Kubuntu from 22.04 to 22.10.
Thanks so much for helping and sharing mate

Comment: Didn't help me.