# No Audio Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.10, pipewire

Just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.10 on my Asus Zenbook 14 OLED (model Q409ZA) but I have no audio. I followed a guide on installing pipewire, but that did not work. I saw some other questions that were related as well but didn't find any solutions. I do see in the settings that the bar is moving when I have audio playing. When I try to do the test audio, nothing is played there either. Attached is a screenshot of the PulseAudio Volume Control output devices. In windows the device is listed as Realtek, so I don't know if there is some kind of driver issue.

Edit:
I did have to reinstall Ubuntu but after the reinstall I did have the same thing - no audio. Followed another guide [Fix No Sound Issue](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/) but the only thing I found a bit weird was my output of `pacmd list-sink-inputs` was `0 sink input(s) available.` even though I had audio going through VLC and Firefox. I tried doing what one of the answers said, which was to do the `inxi -xxz --audio` which showed that pulseaudio was not running. So I did the commands `systemctl --user enable pulseaudio` and `systemctl --user start pulseaudio` which then failed, so I restarted, then started pulseaudio, which did start, but still got no audio, checking the status of pulseaudio again I got the following:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-04-05 14:35:43 CDT; 1min 19s ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
   Main PID: 3144 (pulseaudio)
      Tasks: 8 (limit: 8993)
     Memory: 6.7M
        CPU: 501ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pulseaudio.service
             └─3144 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

Apr 05 14:36:52 ZLaptop pulseaudio[3144]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Apr 05 14:36:52 ZLaptop pulseaudio[3144]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Apr 05 14:36:52 ZLaptop pulseaudio[3144]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Apr 05 14:36:52 ZLaptop pulseaudio[3144]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Apr 05 14:36:52 ZLaptop pulseaudio[3144]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Apr 05 14:36:52 ZLaptop pulseaudio[3144]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Apr 05 14:36:52 ZLaptop pulseaudio[3144]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Apr 05 14:36:57 ZLaptop pulseaudio[3144]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Apr 05 14:36:57 ZLaptop pulseaudio[3144]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Apr 05 14:36:57 ZLaptop pulseaudio[3144]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIsqE.png

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio

systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

[had exactly the same problem and found the solution here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436452/only-dummy-audio-on-laptop-when-updating-from-ubuntu-22-04-to-22-10)

Comment: A link is not an answer. What about later when the link is gone?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue here.

I just love that new laptop but now it seems that every new laptop won't work.

Same happened with the HP envy