# Dummy Output in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: sound, 23.10

Sound Problem: Dummy output:

I am new to Ubuntu 23.10 and Linux and I don't know how to fix problems yet. When I am playing video I got no sound. When I checked the sound section in the Settings app I got this output resource:

[image: output Device: Dummy audio]

When I checked the community I got this resolve for old versions.

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

but I got this error:

[image: Failed to restart pipewire-session-manager.service: Unit pipewire-session-manager.service not found.]

```
Failed to restart pipewire-session-manager.service: 
Unit pipewire-session-manager.service not found
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1436667/864286  Try this to see if it works!