# Only "Dummy Output" appearing for audio in Ubuntu 22.04 and 22.10

Tags: sound, 22.04

I recently purchased an [Intel NUC Laptop](https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/products/sku/225967/intel-nuc-m15-laptop-kit-evo-laprc710/specifications.html) and switched it over to Ubuntu (originally 22.04 LTS, and now 22.10 trying to solve this issue). It seems that Ubuntu is not able to find any audio device on this laptop (when it was briefly on Windows 11 it worked), and in the settings it just says "Dummy Output", and no audio will play.

I have tried [these solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04) and they did not work.

I also ran: `inxi -SMA`

<s>```
System:
  Host: nickt-LAPRC710 Kernel: 5.19.0-26-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME v: 43.1 Distro: Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Intel Client Systems product: LAPRC710 v: M65781-403
    serial: 
  Mobo: Intel model: LAPRC710 v: M65981-402 serial: 
    UEFI: Intel v: RCADL357.0056.2022.0706.1057 date: 07/06/2022
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: N/A
  Device-2: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-26-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes
```</s>

EDIT: re-installed 22.04, re-ran command and got this:

```
System:
  Host: nickt-LAPRC710 Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.5 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Intel Client Systems product: LAPRC710 v: M65781-403
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Intel model: LAPRC710 v: M65981-402 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: Intel v: RCADL357.0056.2022.0706.1057 date: 07/06/2022
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: intel-ipu6
  Device-2: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-56-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

So presumably it's not that the driver is missing?

<s>I noticed that the first audio device has N/A for the driver. Could this be the issue?</s>

EDIT: added output of `alsamixer`

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

*I also don't believe the camera is working with Ubuntu either, the "Cheese" application cannot find the camera, if that might be relevant

Update:

Ran `alsa-info` and got this output:

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=7db2a0b90f51dc00820a376fa4aea0b74f63c2ed

Thank you!!!

Comment: Same problem here. I am not sure if an upcoming sof firmware will fix this. https://github.com/thesofproject/sof/commit/c91326bda26673948f64927cd28fab1c79f2f5d6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works for you, but it did for me with similar problems. Launch the Volume control, go to *Configuration* and set the profile to both input and output (mine was set to input only).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, tried everything solution I could find on AskUbuntu, none of them worked for me. Finally upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04 fixed the problem.

https://releases.ubuntu.com/lunar/

Answer (score 0):

After multiple tries suggested on AskUbuntu and others that didn't work for me, I finally found this and it saved me from becoming crazy:

Pulseaudio and alsa might not be correctly installed and suggested executing the commands below.

$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
$ sudo alsa force-reload

After reboot everything went back to normal with my sound settings.