# No headphones audio on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have an old PC running Ubuntu 20.04.1 with no sound through the headphones. I'm not sure if there's a problem with the speaker output because I currently don't have working speakers to test it.

I've tried these commands:

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

alsamixer

sudo alsa force-reload

pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -D

alsactl restore

sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

---

System info:

```bash
chris@chris-500-223w:~$ uname -a
Linux chris-500-223w 5.15.0-71-generic #78~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 19 11:26:48 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

chris@chris-500-223w:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e10000 irq 32
 1 [Webcam         ]: USB-Audio - C922 Pro Stream Webcam
                      C922 Pro Stream Webcam at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, high speed

chris@chris-500-223w:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: 92HD66C3/65 Analog [92HD66C3/65 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


chris@chris-500-223w:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [103c:2af7]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

-- UPDATE --
I upgraded to 22.04 and applied all updates

In Settings/Sound/Output/Output Device the only item available was "Dummy Output"

I followed the directions given here:
[No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04)

and ran these commands:

`sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio`

`systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager`

Settings/Sound/Output/Output Device was updated correctly,
but even with "Headphones - Built-in Audio" selected there's no sound.

Next, I ran these commands:

`pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start`

`sudo alsa force-reload`

`sudo alsactl restore`

without success.

```bash
chris@chris-500-223w:~$ uname -a
Linux chris-500-223w 5.15.0-71-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 18 09:00:29 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

chris@chris-500-223w:~$ lspci -v | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller

chris@chris-500-223w:~$ aplay --list-devices
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: I've updated my question - I did upgrade to 22.04, but I've got the same problem.