# Sound input devices not detected in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, pipewire

I've recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and my input and output built-in sound devices weren't detected by the system. After trying every option described in [No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04), I was able to fix built-in speakers by adding `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` into `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`.

The issue with input devices (built-in microphone) not being detected remains. There are no problems related to the hardware, as the microphone is working in Windows 11, Ubuntu 20.04, and live Ubuntu 22.04.

#### Information related to the problem

This is how my settings are in Ubuntu 22.04:
[input devices window is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWcAU.png)
and this is how it looks in Ubuntu 22.04 *live*
[microphone is detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rthwx.png)

Hardware, drivers, and kernel version: HP envy 15-ep0xxx laptop with

```
uname -a
Linux andrii-HP-ENVY-Laptop-15-ep0xxx 6.2.0-32-generic #32~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 18 10:40:13 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:1aeb] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company TU116 High Definition Audio Controller [103c:878d]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
01:00.2 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB 3.1 Host Controller [10de:1aec] (rev a1)
```

Here I compare configurations of usual and live ubuntu correspondingly:

1. live

   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ `arecord -l`

   **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

   card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 6: DMIC (*) []

   Subdevices: 0/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 7: DMIC16kHz (*) []

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ `aplay -l`

   **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

   card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []

   Subdevices: 0/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ `pactl info`

   Server String: /run/user/999/pulse/native

   Library Protocol Version: 35

   Server Protocol Version: 35

   Is Local: yes

   Client Index: 15

   Tile Size: 65472

   User Name: ubuntu

   Host Name: ubuntu

   Server Name: pulseaudio

   Server Version: 15.99.1

   Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz

   Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right

   Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink

   Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_6__source
   Cookie: d5f6:7302
2. usual: as you can see, the microphone is not listed here

   andrii@andrii-HP-ENVY-Laptop-15-ep0xxx  ~  `arecord -l`

   **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC245 Analog [ALC245 Analog]

   Subdevices: 0/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   andrii@andrii-HP-ENVY-Laptop-15-ep0xxx  ~  `aplay -l`

   **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC245 Analog [ALC245 Analog]

   Subdevices: 0/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

   card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]

   Subdevices: 1/1

   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

andrii@andrii-HP-ENVY-Laptop-15-ep0xxx  ~  `pactl info`

Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native

Library Protocol Version: 35

Server Protocol Version: 35

Is Local: yes

Client Index: 107

Tile Size: 65472

User Name: andrii

Host Name: andrii-HP-ENVY-Laptop-15-ep0xxx

Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.48)

Server Version: 15.0.0

Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz

Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right

Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo

Default Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor

Cookie: c9ba:a9b4

Here is also my codec:

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC245
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
Codec: Nvidia GPU 99 HDMI/DP
```

##### What I tried that didn't work:

1. reinstalling completely alsa, pulseaudio:

   `sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio`

   `sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio`

   `sudo alsa force-reload`
2. restarting pulseaudio instance:

   `pulseaudio -k`

   `pulseaudio -D`
3. restarting pulseaudio service:

   `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service`

   `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.socket`
4. using pipewire insdead of pulseaudio:

   `sudo apt install pipewire-audio-client-libraries`
   `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service`

   `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket`

   `systemctl --user disable pulseaudio.service`

   `systemctl --user disable pulseaudio.socket`

   `systemctl --user start pipewire.service`

   `systemctl --user start pipewire-pulse.service`

   `systemctl --user enable pipewire.service`

   `systemctl --user enable pipewire-pulse.service`
5. removing configuration files:

   `rm -r ~/.config/pulse`
6. running

   `sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio`

   `systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager`

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Completely reinstalling Ubuntu solved the problem, but I can't really recommend such a "solution".

Comment: After a wild goose chase, what worked for me in the end was using the SOF drivers via grub - this is done by setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash loglevel=3 snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=3"` in /etc/default/grub then running `sudo update-grub`. This flag replaced `dmic_detect=0` which was suggested in some places.