# No sound Civ 5 and wine

Tags: 12.04, sound, wine

I have installed Civilization 5 retail version with an update pack called update 7 via WINE and while the game runs well I am unable to get any sound working.

I am running 12.04 and version 1.4 of WINE via APT.

Any suggestions on how I could get sound working?

Comment: It would help to know the version of the game (Steam, etc.) and the version of wine you're using, latest is not specific enough, it really depends on your repo configuration.

Comment: Did you install `d3dx90_36` with winetricks? Check out [Civilization 5 on WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21492).

Comment: Yes it was pre installed

Comment: @markkirby  I see you have had no luck with this question, did you ever get it working.  I answered a similar question today the answer may help you, check it out http://askubuntu.com/questions/173994/no-sound-on-wolfenstien-et/174179#174179.  Let me know if it works and i will add it as an answer.

Comment: There is a Linux port for Civ 5 at this point, so Wine is no longer required.

Answer (score 1):

On appdb, there was an entry for Civ5 with a wine 1.4

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21492&iTestingId=69848

There, the user said:

Works perfect, needed to kill pulseaudio to make sound work.

Give it a try =P

Comment: as to *how* you can kill/prevent pulseaudio from working, well ...

http://askubuntu.com/questions/8425/how-to-temporarily-disable-pulseaudio

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this did not help.

Comment: did you follow the link to the ways to kill pulse ? One should note that pulse auto-respawns, so a simple `killall -9 pulseaudio` is not enough

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on Wine, but the following solution has helped a number of people with sound problems on wine (it does work for 64bit too).

> Marvin Mallari posted to Ubuntu 15 hours ago - For people having sound problems with Wine (like sound is garbled, static, non existant) in Ubuntu 12.04 (w/ Unity and Pulse/ALSA) i found a solution. Go to Synaptic Package Manager, install "ia32-libs-multiarch", it will ask to modify or install other packages, install all packages and restart (not log out then log in) Wine should now play audio perfectly and stable. note: i did this on a 32bit comp, for 64bit, there is probably a different package or maybe the package will work because it says "multiarch" i will try on my 64bit machine later. PS i don't have an account on any Wine or Ubuntu fourms so if someone can please share this somewhere that needs it that would be much appreciated!
>
> Marvin Mallari - Ia32 probably isn't the solution but when I read the
>   addition packages synaptic modifies and installs, a couple of them are
>   for pulse so it is probably those packages that fixed it but in any
>   case ia32 installed whatever it needed to work. It also seems like
>   pulse cpu usage has dropped.

Comment: This did not work either im afraid im starting to think this is a lost cause but will leave the bounty open if people still want to try Thanks for your answer