# Unable to install osspd

Tags: unity, lts

I try to install osspd, but I get the message that I need the library lib6c >= 2.17

I tried to install it by:
apt-get install osspd
http://sourceforge.net/projects/osspd/
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/raring/universe/base/osspd

apt-cache policy osspd
N: Unable to locate package osspd

version:
cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.5.0-34-generic (buildd@roseapple) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #55~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 7 16:25:50 UTC 2013

All with the same result.
not easy to backport to 12.10 LTS??!!

!!!!!Nevermind
Since what I wanted was to have the sound back working, I follow the thread:
[No sound Civ 5 and wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168446/no-sound-civ-5-and-wine)

I installed ia32-libs-multiarc, so that did the trick

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running? What is the output of `apt-cache policy osspd`? If your requirement of libc6 isn't met on your system you're probably not running Ubuntu 13.04, because 13.04 [has 2.17](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libc6) and earlier Ubuntu releases [have older versions](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libc6). The package is [only available in 13.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=osspd) at the time of writing. Please *edit* your question to provide the details requested.

Comment: Please do not put the answer to the question in the question itself. Please answer your won question in the **Your Answer** window below and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail)

It appears that you're running Ubuntu 12.10. In this version the package isn't available. After upgrading to 13.04, your package management will be able to locate and install the package properly for you.

Why? [packages.ubuntu.com search for `osspd`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=osspd) shows an entry for 13.04 only at the time of writing.

Manually installing/compiling the version in 12.10 will be very hard - the dependencies like libc6 >= 2.17 will not be met. To me it seems this is not easy to backport to 12.10.

Comment: I follow the thread: