# how to disable internal speaker audio

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio

Under 12.04 :

How do I disable globally the internal speaker of my computer without having to unset it to each user session ?

I've tried to add "blacklist pcspkr" into "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist" but it still let pulseaudio to use the internal speaker.

Here is the lsmod that doesn't appear to show the pc speaker working :

```
Module                  Size  Used by
coretemp               13361  0
dcdbas                 14098  0
snd_hda_codec_via      46188  1
microcode              18395  0
snd_hda_intel          33028  5
snd_hda_codec         116476  2 snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                81052  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0
snd_rawmidi            25425  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              13031  0
lpc_ich                16992  0
snd_seq                51568  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
hid_generic            12445  0
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    62520  17 snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
mac_hid                13077  0
soundcore              14635  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lp                     17455  0
parport                40930  1 lp
usbhid                 46022  0
hid                    82474  2 hid_generic,usbhid
aufs                  159970  69
overlayfs              27511  0
squashfs               36095  1
nbd                    17427  1
r8169                  56852  0
i915                  470739  0
drm_kms_helper         45427  1 i915
drm                   231841  2 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13316  1 i915
video                  19069  1 i915
```

However I'm hearing music from the pc speaker.

Maybe it's at the pulseaudio level but how to do the change global and not limited to one user ?

Thank you !

Comment: What I usually do is just disconnect the internal speaker - I only ever used them for POST diagnosis anyway

Comment: it is solded to the mainboard :(

Comment: I think these links might help you.  [How to temporarily disable Pulseaudio?][1]

  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/8425/how-to-temporarily-disable-pulseaudio

Comment: be sure to add `blacklist pcspkr` to the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` file

Comment: the lsmod show this :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options I guess might work: [How_to_disable_the_pc_speaker_(beep!)](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_disable_the_pc_speaker_(beep!))

Comment: It helped me a little but pulseaudio still uses the internal speaker .... lsmod doesn't show the two modules loaded so it had at least effect on this. Still looking for disabling the pc speaker.

Answer (score 3):

You can try from terminal the command `alsamixer`

**alsamixer** is the alsa provided ncurses GUI for accessing hardware mixer elements, and it is capable of seperately turning off the internal speaker.

see man page of alsamixer for more infor `man alsamixer`

Also, if you want raw access to sound card parameters, you can use **amixer** which is a command-line mixer for ALSA soundcard driver

`amixer -c<n>` should provide that list

`amixer -c<num> set <SCONTROL>` mute will mute a mutable control by name

Be sure to check out various values of  with amixer,the -c argument for selecting a sound card also works with alsamixer or amixer.

You can also install a GUI for **alsamixer**

```
sudo apt-get install alsamixergui
```

Comment: The trouble of alsamixer is that it's inside a user session. I need to block it global.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. This helped:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disable_PC_Speaker_Beep

specifically, I used the alsa mixer in terminal to mute the pc speaker.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to mute the internal pc speaker from alsamixer for some reason (in earlier cases over the years that always worked):

However, this time the Pulse Audio Control (ubuntu package pavucontrol) had one of the Output options which muted the pc speaker and let my headphones the signal.

Try using Pulse Audio Control (`apt-get install pavucontrol`, or launch from dash if already installed) and use controls within `Output Options` to mute the internal speaker while maintaining an audio stream to headphones.

Answer (score 0):

In disabling globally the internal speaker of my computer your meaning turning off the sound to the speakers.  So no sound comes out when your either logging in or anything else.  Killing the pulse audio daemon would do it.  You can do this by entering in command line "pactl exit" to turn off the pulse audio daemon and "pulseaudio" to turn pulseaudo on. This just turns it on and off.  The man of pactl will give you a litte more information which might help

[man pact](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pactl)

I found the link below useful.  A more permanent way off doing what I think you want to happen.  I know I don't like the sound coming out when starting up.  I like a volume knob. I hope this helps.

[How to temporarily disable Pulseaudio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8425/how-to-temporarily-disable-pulseaudio)

Comment: by the internal speaker I mean that what is normally used to make beep is also used to produce sound ... So I have sound coming out from my box (a DELL FX170). It's not a localized issue : many HP desktop and all in one have similar issues. It's like that the "beeper" is connected to the soundcard ....

Comment: try running in command line sudo lsmod |grep pcspkr if pcspkr is listed then you can disable it using sudo modprobe -r pcspkr then add the the line “blacklist pcspkr” to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist to turn off permanently.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: Done but still having the issue.