# Volume mutes when set below ~20% 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, volume-control

Since updating to 14.04, I'm unable to set a lower volume. According to the alsamixer, it automatically mutes when I try to go below 18%.

How can I restore access to the quieter volumes?
Ubuntu 14.04 running on a Dell Inspiron 1501

Comment: Are you sure it mutes, and isn't just that it is too quiet to hear?

Comment: Yes. looking in alsamixer, it goes from 18 to muted. listening in my headphones, it goes from "louder than I'd like" to "silence"

Comment: What does the command `pactl set-sink-volume 2 15%` do? Does that also mute it, or go to 15%?

Comment: Yes. It also goes to silent. Using the pactl set-sink-volume 0 XX% command reveals that the sound cuts on at 17% and above and is silent at 16% and below (index 0 used, because others do not exist)

Comment: That's very odd, I think it's a bug and needs to be reported on http://launchpad.net

Comment: I've noticed in the past that PulseAudio will turn the normal range of volumes into only about 5-7 different levels (despite the fact that the computer still treats it as a percentage). What I did was [disable PulseAudio](http://askubuntu.com/a/10307/187281). See if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Disabling PulseAudio prevented RhythmBox from playing, so that is not workable solution for me. Thanks though.

Answer (score 9):

Setting `volume-limit` works for headphones but will, probably, make sound too quiet while using other speakers.

As alternative solution, try setting `ignore_dB=1` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

```
load-module module-udev-detect ignore_dB=1
```

From [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#No_sound_below_a_volume_cutoff_or_Clipping_on_a_particular_output_device)

Comment: This fixes my issue with an USB sound card (041e:30d3 SoundBlaster Play). The pulse audio system volume now is in sync with the output "Speaker" mixer, both start at 0%.

Comment: Works like a charm with a USB headset on ubuntu 20.10

Comment: Worked for me. But the sound is too high right now. Either my speakers has always been so powerful, or linux overloads them.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution [here](https://chrisjean.com/fix-for-usb-audio-is-too-loud-and-mutes-at-low-volume-in-ubuntu/) worked for me.

As root, you'll need to edit the file:

```
$ sudo vim /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common
```

Find the section that looks like the following:

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

Add a new setting for `volume-limit` so it looks like this:

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
volume-limit = 0.05    # This is the new line
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

Then you need to restart PulseAudio with the following command:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
```

If you had any applications playing sound, they will be muted.  You'll have to restart them to get sound again and then you can test your new settings.

The original author of the solution suggested setting `volume-limit = 0.01`, but I found that to be too quiet, so I use `0.05`.  You can test smaller or larger values to fit your preferences.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem, it just reduces the volume of my whole system...

Comment: It broke the system: linux cannot recognize the sound card anymore. Beware!

Answer (score 4):

I've also had this problem for several years now in all the releases of Ubuntu.

@Tim, it is already reported in launchpad. Related bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/443131

According to the last comment, this bug won't be fixed :(

PS: This was meant to be / should have been a comment like the ones above, but apparently I need 50 reputation points to be able to do that..

Answer (score 0):

I found I had a similar problem: with my Antlion USB adapter (which I bought with my ModMic 4 setup), volume would completely mute below 25%, and at 25%, it was pretty loud.

The solution I found, in `pavucontrol`, is to go into `Configuration` and pick the `Pro Audio` profile (default is `Analog Stereo Output + Mono Input`). This gives me a much smooth range of volumes, all the way down to zero percent. I can actually get it down to a level that is barely perceptible to me (~-60dB).

And of course recording still works. So all good!

Note that before switching to `Pro Audio` mode, it might be better to put the ALSA mixer volume to its maximum, as that will be the 100% mark in Pulseaudio/PipeWire after... In my first experiments, the 100% volume was quite not loud enough. Now, of course, 100% is much *too* loud, but sometimes you do want it really loud... ;)

I'm on Debian 12 "bookworm" (currently in testing), with a Pipewire 0.3.60 audio backend. The exact USB device is:

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0d8c:002b C-Media Electronics, Inc. Antlion USB adapter
```

So this might not help your actual case, but I hope it may help others having this problem.