# Volume slider not working

Tags: 14.04, sound, volume-control

Every once in a while, my sound stops working.  So, I did what I normally do and reinstalled alsa-base, pulseaudio, and libasound2 then restarted.  After reboot, the sound worked again, but the volume slider has no effect on master volume, which I can change through alsamixer.  How could I fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: Try [disabling PulseAudio](http://askubuntu.com/q/8425/187281). It has been my experience that PulseAudio causes a host of audio issues on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Go to pulseaudio --> output devices --> click on the lock. Worked for me. When hovering over the lock, it says `lock channels together`.

Comment: I can't find any "pulseaudio -> output devices -> et cetera". Please be more specific.